# How does the Presentation-/ViewModel for a Task or Dialog look like?

Tags: language-agnostic, design-patterns, mvvm

I'm trying to move to a Model/ViewModel/View architecture and got stuck when trying to push selection dialogs to this pattern. I'd like to separate retrieving a list of choices (business/presentation logic) and the actual displaying/choosing mechanism (view) to re-use the former with different views (e.g. ComboBox vs. modal dialog).

How would a ViewModel for such a selection task look like? Or am I trying to hard, and I should implement this in the View only?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you would like to use the implementation to retrieve list?? If so, I think you can create a service class in the application layer and reuse the functionality..