# Inheriting from Window in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, inheritance, mvvm

I'm trying to implement the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1486481/154439.  In the author's [solution](http://www.japf.fr/2009/09/how-to-close-a-view-from-a-viewmodel/) he writes,

> I created an abstract ApplicationWindowBase class that inherits from Window.

I am not sure what he means here.  I tried changing my XAML from `<Window ...` to `<ApplicationWindowBase ...`.  No luck.

The designer-generated file for the window inherits from System.Windows.Window, but as that file is designer-generated, making changes to it does me no good.  I've tried various other approaches with no success.

I am very new to both WPF and MVVM.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You need to inherit the code behind and the xaml from your base class.  To do so in the xaml you will also need a reference to the namespace / binary the class is in before it will let you declare it.  The syntax is something like `xmlns myPrefix=pathtoclass` then `<myPrefix:ApplicationWindowBase>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code to go along with Kevin's comment:

**Code Behind**

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : ApplicationWindowBase
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<myPrefix:ApplicationWindowBase x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:myPrefix="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
        Title="TestWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</myPrefix:ApplicationWindowBase>
```

Just make sure you use the correct namespace, mine happens to be StackOverflow.

Comment: It looks like for my purposes I don't need MainWindow to inherit from ApplicationWindowBase in the code behind.  The XAML section of your answer was enough to get me going.  Thanks.

Comment: @TrueEddie: What, you didn't ninja edit?  And that implication is in your head, not in my comment :)

Answer (score 1):

First, xaml or not, these are all classes.  Therefore, anything inheriting from another class (i.e., Window), must do so as any other class.

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public sealed class MyWindow : Window
    {
        public object SomeNewProperty {get;set;}
    }
}
```

xaml is just a different type of serialization with its own set of rules.  But it's still serialized XML, and as such everything must be traceable back to its original type.

How xaml does this is through a facility in XML called "namespaces".  They fit well with our understanding of namespaces as C# developers, as we must map an XML namespace to a namespace in our application so that the xaml serializer can match an XML element with a CLR type.

Xaml uses a couple different ways of matching these namespaces.  One looks like a URL and is defined by an assembly attribute (e.g., "xmlns="http://microsoft.com/whatevs").  This works when the assembly is external to the one you are writing in.  In your case, you'll have to use the other method of identifying your namespace.  This specialized XML namespace is parsed by the xaml serializer in order to identify the namespace and containing assembly of your classes.  It goes by the form "clr-namespace:SomeNamespace;assembly=SomeAssembly".  You can omit the assembly bit if the type is in the current assembly.

To put it all together with the above example, you would create an instance of your new window like this:

```
<t:MyWindow 
    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:SomeNamespace" 
    xmlns="the standard microsoft namespace here"
    t:OmitOtherStuffBecauseThisIsAnExampleLol="true">
```