# Where is good place to register Messenger responsible for showing Windows to ensure MVVM pattern Separation of Concerns and Testability not violated?

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light, separation-of-concerns

Scenario:

MainWindow has a Menu About which relates to AboutWindow.

About Meny is triggered by command:

```
<MenuItem Header="_About" Command="{Binding OpenAbout}"/>
```

OpenAbout is property like that:

```
  private RelayCommand _openAbout;
        public RelayCommand OpenAbout
        {
            get
            {
                return _openAbout ?? (_openAbout = new RelayCommand(() => Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("ShowAboutView"))));
            }
        }
```

Notification message is registered in App.cs class as follows:

```
 static App()
        {
            DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
        }

        public App()
        {
            RegisterMessenger();
        }

        public void RegisterMessenger()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, ProcessShowAboutView);          
        }

        private void ProcessShowAboutView(NotificationMessage message)
        {
            AboutWindow view = new AboutWindow();
            view.Show();
        }
```

I analysed another questions like that:

[How to open a new window using MVVM Light Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386349/how-to-open-a-new-window-using-mvvm-light-toolkit)

[WPF MVVM - How to Show a view from MainWindowViewModel upon Clicking on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829413/wpf-mvvm-how-to-show-a-view-from-mainwindowviewmodel-upon-clicking-on-button)

I like Messenger functionality but however I am not sure If above solution is a good one.
I would be thankful for any advise!

As depicted above, Registering messages is done in App Config.
I consider it not be a good place therefore I need to know what place would be better.
Another place to consider would be Locator

Comment: The `App` constructor is the perfect place to register message handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personaly would register the messages in `App.xaml.cs` in the `OnStartup` method (WPF) and in the set up method of the unit test (dont forget to unregister everything in the tear down method).

Comment: thanks for quick response, do you think that this solution is better than Constructor of ViewModelLocator? Can you point out antyadvantages of your proposal?

Comment: There is another aspect: given I know how to create windows, what about closing them? Shoult it also be done in App.xaml.cs? Is there any good practise about such known issue?