# How to open a new window in C# MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have tried for 2 days how to open a new window in WPF MVVM.

I have read a lot of articles and questions on stackoverflow. 
In this question [WPF MVVM - How to Show a view from MainWindowViewModel upon Clicking on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829413/wpf-mvvm-how-to-show-a-view-from-mainwindowviewmodel-upon-clicking-on-button)
there was an answer where mak gave 4 examples, and any of it doesn't want to work :(

for example I have this code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Ranking view = new Ranking();
        view.Show();
    }
```

where Ranking is a view and I get an error like missing assembly reference and no extension method 'Show' accepting a first agrument. In mediator pattern I've got also error like:

The name 'Messenger' does not exist in the current context
and
The type or namespace name 'AddCustomerMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please help I don't have any ideas how to fix it or if somebody have an example project to download please share it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: event handlers is not great idea for MVVM-pattern, especially handlers contains some business-logic. It is an article about event handling in MVVM: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18199.event-handling-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application.aspx

Comment: yea Ok but why I get error in view.Show()?

Comment: Can you provide code of your RankingView?

Comment: I don't have anything there, should i add something there?

Comment: @Icet how do you initialize Ranking?