# Why is the WPF ApplicationCommands.Close command disabled on the button and in the menu item?

Tags: wpf, xaml, icommand

#### Question

Why is the WPF [ApplicationCommands.Close](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5016139/33311) command disabled on the button and in the menu item?

#### Code

```
<Window x:Class="ApplicationCloseCommand.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ApplicationCloseCommand.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="169.493" Width="319.273">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Command="Close"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <Canvas>
            <Button Content="Close" Command="Close" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="142" Canvas.Top="31"/>
        </Canvas>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

#### Research

[Some sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1066054) say to implement an `ICommand` yourself and do a `this.Close()` in the command handler. But then, I don't understand why `ApplicationCommands.Close` exists at all.

[Some sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-enable-a-command) say that one needs to implement a `CanExecute` methode to return `true`. But again, if I have to do that myself including the `CloseCommandHandler` (from the linked example), what's the benefit of `ApplicationCommands.Close`?

[Some sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5016139/33311) mention a `CommandTarget`. This didn't work:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Exit" Command="Close" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyMainWindow}"/>
```

Did I just do it wrong with the `CommandTarget`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ApplicationCommands`, like `NavigationCommands` and `ComponentCommands` exposes set of predefined common UI commands. They are all implementations of `RoutedCommand`. `RoutedCommand` or `RoutedUICommand`implement `ICommand`.

`RoutedCommand` doesn't implement an `Execute` or `CanExecute` method. It just raises the corresponding `RoutedEvent`.

This event will traverse the visual tree until it is handled by a `CommandBinding`. It's the `CommandBinding` that defines or executes the `CanExecute` and `Execute` methods or special event handlers. This means the actual command implementations can be defined somewhere on the tree on which the `RoutedCommand` was raised.

There are a few controls that implement a default `CommandBinding` (or command implementation). `TextBox` can handle e.g. the `ApplicationCommands.Copy` `RoutedCommand`. Or the `DocumentViewer` can handle the NavigationCommands.NextPage RoutedCommand. `ApplicationCommands.Close` has no supporter or default implementation provided by any control.

`RoutedCommand` is designed to be used in UI context e.g. executing behaviour of a control. This kind of logic should never be handled in the view model. Therefore `ApplicationCommands.Close` must be implemented by a control or an attached behaviour that hooks into the visual tree.
For data related behaviour or logic you must provide your own `ICommand` implementation, which has the handlers defined in the view model.

If you assign a `RoutedCommand` e.g., `ApplicationCommands.Close`  to a command source e.g. a `Button`, but don't provide a handler for this `RoutedCommand` and therefore no `CanExecute` handler exists the command source e.g. `Button` assumes `CanExecute` is false and disables itself.

This means you must provide a `CommandBinding`:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Close}"
                    Executed="ExecutedCloseCommand"
                    CanExecute="CanExecuteCloseCommand" />
  </Window.CommandBindings>

  <Button Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Close}"
          Content="Close Window"/>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void CanExecuteCloseCommand(object sender,
    CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   e.CanExecute = true;
}

private void ExecutedCloseCommand(object sender,
    ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  this.Close();
}
```