# WPF MVVM DialogService close modal dialog?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dialog, modal-dialog

I use the MVVM-pattern in my WPF-application. Now I show a dialog with my dialogService:

```
_dialogService.ShowDialog(Me, settingsViewModel)
```

The mapping (which view should be shown to this ViewModel) was set in the WindowViewModelMappings class.

My question is now: How can I close the dialog from the settingsViewModel?

Thank you..

Comment: Seems to be duplicate of 
[this one][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501886/wpf-mvvm-newbie-how-should-the-viewmodel-close-the-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more about the implementation, I'd recommend you to return a token (guid, ...), that represents that dialog.
And then you have a call to close the dialog where you pass in that token.