# Bind a views DialogResult to a ViewModels property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding, dialogresult

I am relatively new to WPF, XAML and Data-bindings. I have a view (Window) and a view-model.

I have tried to implement the MVVM pattern which means neither the view nor the view-model hold a reference to each other. All data exchange happens via data-bindings.

So far so good but now I have run into a problem I can't find a solution for.

On my view I have a button Start which is bound to a command.

```
<Button Command="{Binding NextCommand}" Content="Next">
```

NextCommand is of type `ActionCommand : ICommand`

In my case NextCommand simply calls a private method within the view-model.

The problem I can not find a solution so far is the following:

How to close the window at the end of the view-models NextCommandAction method?

```
private void NextCommandAction(object o)
{
    ...
    ...
    // close the window
}
```

Since I do not have a reference to the view I can not just set `DialogResult = true;`

The only working solution I have found so far is to add a hidden radio-button to the view and bind it's value to a property CloseView and create a method CloseView within the xaml.cs file which is bound to the Checked event of the hidden radio-button. Within that method I set DialogResult = true;

Although this works I feel like there has to be a better solution than adding hidden elements to your view!

Comment: An answer on how to bind the DialogResult from the Window to the ViewModel could be found here: [How should the ViewModel close the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/501886/9758687)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the window reference as CommandParameter to the Close command and do whatever required on the window.

```
<Button Content="Close" Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}" 
  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Window}"/>

private void CloseCommand(object sender)
{
    Window wnd = sender as Window;
    wnd.Close();
}
```

Comment: Where's the view model part of this answer?

Answer (score 1):

`CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Window}"` assumes that you have an element in your XAML named "Window". e.g, your Window tag would need `Name="Window"`

Answer (score 0):

This question was one of the first things that came up when I googled to check if `DialogResult` is a dependency property (it isn't :-) )

Add a dependency property to your Window:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty InteractionResultProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(InteractionResult),
                typeof(Boolean?),
                typeof(MyWpfWindow1),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Boolean?), 
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                    OnInteractionResultChanged));

  public Boolean? InteractionResult
        {
            get => (Boolean?) GetValue(InteractionResultProperty);
            set => SetValue(InteractionResultProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnInteractionResultChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((MyWpfWindow1) d).DialogResult = e.NewValue as Boolean?;
        }
```

I named my property InteractionResult though a good name would have also worked.

In the xaml right after the 
you can bind it with a style

```
 <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type z:MyWpfWindow1}">
            <Setter Property="InteractionResult"
                    Value="{Binding UpdateResult}" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
```

UpdateResult is the property in my viewmodel.

```
  private Boolean? _updateResult;

        public Boolean? UpdateResult
        {
            get => _updateResult;
            set => SetValue(ref _updateResult, value);
        }
```

The SetValue method is the usual notify property

```
 protected virtual Boolean SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, 
            [CallerMemberName]String propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Equals(field, value))
                return false;

            field = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
```

and the property gets set in the usual way

```
<Button Content="Cancel" 
        Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" />
```

```
ICommand CancelCommand { get; }


private void OnCancel()
{
   UpdateResult = false;
}
```

Disclaimer: works on my computer.

Comment: Sorry for the newbie questions. But you use GetValue and SetValue when laying out defining a DependencyProperty but they are not defined. Then it appears a different SetValue is defined at the end of the post. Would you mind laying out the code for these methods? Thank you.

Comment: GetValue and SetValue are defined in DependencyObject which would the eventual base class of any visual type where a dependency property can be defined https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyobject?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Chandrashekhar Joshi's answer
(but not using the elements's name):

Define CommandParameter in Button:

```
<Button
  Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"
  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
  Content="Close" />
```

Define Command (and Implementation):

```
CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand<Window>((w) => w.DialogResult = true);
```

Comment: Passing a UI control to the ViewModel goes against everything that MVVM stands for. A MVVM pure method of closing a window from the ViewModel is using an attached property - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3329467/967885