# How to bring window to front with wpf and using mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a window that essentially runs a timer.   When the timer hits 0 I want to bring the window to the front so that it is visible and not hidden behind some other application.

From what I can gather I would simply call window.activate() to accomplish this but with mvvm my view model doesn't have a reference to window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go about it in a couple of ways - adding a reference to the window could work since the viewmodel is not coupled with the view but related to it, but I don't really like that approach since it pretty much does couple your view to your viewmodel - which is not really the point of MVVM

A better approach may be to have your viewmodel raise an event or a command which the view can handle. This way the view gets to decide what UI action is associated with the command/event

e.g. simply

```
class SomeView 
{
    void HandleSomeCommandOrEvent() 
    {
        this.Activate();
    }
}
```

Of course how you wire this up is up to you but I'd probably try and get routed commands happening

Edit: You can't really 'bind' a simple event, since it's invoked from the viewmodel.

A simple event based example is just to add the event to the viewmodel and handle it directly ... e.g. imagine the following MainWindow with a ViewModel property

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MainWindowViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        ViewModel.ShowMessage += ViewModel_ShowMessage;
        this.DataContext = ViewModel;
    }

    void ViewModel_ShowMessage(object sender, ShowMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Some caption", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }

}
```

Then the ViewModel can just fire the event:

```
// The view model
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    // The button click command
    public RelayCommand ButtonClickCommand { get; set; }

    // The event to fire
    public event EventHandler<ShowMessageEventArgs> ShowMessage;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {            
        ButtonClickCommand = new RelayCommand(ButtonClicked);            
    }

    void ButtonClicked(object param)
    {
        // This button is wired up in the view as normal and fires the event
        OnShowMessage("You clicked the button");
    }

    // Fire the event - it's up to the view to decide how to implement this event and show a message
    void OnShowMessage(string message)
    {
        if (ShowMessage != null) ShowMessage(this, new ShowMessageEventArgs(message));
    }
}

public class ShowMessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public ShowMessageEventArgs(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

The XAML would be:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}">Click me!</Button>
```

So the button invokes the command, which in turn fires the event which the view (MainWindow) handles and shows a messagebox. This way the view/UI decides on the course of action based on the type of event raised. Of course it could be your timer which fired the event

You can always go down the more involved route such as some of the answers on this question...

[How should the ViewModel close the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501886/wpf-mvvm-newbie-how-should-the-viewmodel-close-the-form)

but to be honest, it depends if you really need it - a simple event works well - some people overcomplicate things for the sake of elegance, but at the detriment of simplicity and productivity!

Comment: I am learning wpf and binding so this may be a simple question.  How do you bind a command to the view?  I am doing this with buttons but I don't know how to do this without a wpf control  <Button Content="Add Task" Command="{Binding Path=AddTask}"/> where AddTask is an ICommand.

Answer (score 21):

A "purist" MVVM solution is to use a behavior. Below is a behavior for a `Window` with an `Activated` property. Setting the property to true will activate the window (and restore it if it is minimized):

```
public class ActivateBehavior : Behavior<Window> {

  Boolean isActivated;

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ActivatedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Activated",
      typeof(Boolean),
      typeof(ActivateBehavior),
      new PropertyMetadata(OnActivatedChanged)
    );

  public Boolean Activated {
    get { return (Boolean) GetValue(ActivatedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ActivatedProperty, value); }
  }

  static void OnActivatedChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    var behavior = (ActivateBehavior) dependencyObject;
    if (!behavior.Activated || behavior.isActivated)
      return;
    // The Activated property is set to true but the Activated event (tracked by the
    // isActivated field) hasn't been fired. Go ahead and activate the window.
    if (behavior.AssociatedObject.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
      behavior.AssociatedObject.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    behavior.AssociatedObject.Activate();
  }

  protected override void OnAttached() {
    AssociatedObject.Activated += OnActivated;
    AssociatedObject.Deactivated += OnDeactivated;
  }

  protected override void OnDetaching() {
    AssociatedObject.Activated -= OnActivated;
    AssociatedObject.Deactivated -= OnDeactivated;
  }

  void OnActivated(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
    this.isActivated = true;
    Activated = true;
  }

  void OnDeactivated(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
    this.isActivated = false;
    Activated = false;
  }

}
```

The behavior requires a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`. Fortunately, this is now available on NuGet in the [Blend.Interactivity.Wpf](https://nuget.org/packages/Blend.Interactivity.Wpf/) package.

The behavior is attached to a Window in XAML like this:

```
<Window ...>
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Behaviors:ActivateBehavior Activated="{Binding Activated, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The view-model should expose a boolean `Activated` property. Setting this property to true will activate the window (unless it is already activated). As an added bonus it will also restore a minimized window.

Comment: Thx Martin. This is the real answer, not the event hacking.

Comment: What will happen when you set the `Activated` property to `false`?

Comment: @RomanKo: Nothing except the property becomes false, but you are not supposed to set it to false. Set the property to true to activate the window and get the property value to determine if the window is activated.

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;    
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging; 

// View

public partial class TestActivateWindow : Window
{
    public TestActivateWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Messenger.Default.Register<ActivateWindowMsg>(this, (msg) => Activate());
    }
}

// View Model

public class MainViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    ICommand _activateChildWindowCommand;

    public ICommand ActivateChildWindowCommand {
        get {
            return _activateChildWindowCommand?? (_activateChildWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(() => {
                Messenger.Default.Send(new ActivateWindowMsg());
        }));
        }
    }
}

public class ActivateWindowMsg
{
}
```