# How to set a combobox to NULL, if the value cannot be NULL

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

How can I set a combobox to null in C# using WPF?

I have implemented two languages (German and English). Always when I select one, all comboboxes are cleared. That works fine. The problem is, if a item of a combobox is selected, that the application crashes.

German: Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein. Parametername: source

English: The value cannot be NULL. Parameter name: source

Does anyone know how to fix the problem?

Comment: How are you clearing the combobox?

Comment: Like this: comboBox_1.Items.Clear();

Comment: Post your current code. It is very likely that you're doing a `.FirstOrDefault()` or other LINQ operation on a `null` collection. This has nothing to do with WPF and is an exception caused by a bug in your code. Also, please learn MVVM before ever writing a single line of code in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore "Also, please learn MVVM before ever writing a single line of code in WPF" Yeah, MVVM is good, but it sounds a bit overrated for me... Dunno, maybe MVVM is not the best solution in 100% of time

Comment: @Guilherme Yeah, I'm pretty sure hacking your way thru UI virtualization using `VisualTreeHelper` is really much better than using proper DataBinding... Please....

Comment: @HighCore I agree with you that MVVM is good in almost any situation, but what I mean is that is not 100% of the situations. For example, in a Window that you have sure that will be ever with the same Model, and you are using a lot of events, like the mouse right click in some elements, or other events... Is a lot easier to write this without MVVM, IMO... Into some simple code behind.

Comment: @GUilherme I don't understand your last comment. And no, nothing is "easier" if you disregard DataBinding and use archaic winforms-like techniques in WPF. BTW, MVVM has nothing to do with any mouse events or the like. That's a UI concern which MVVM does not care about. MVVM is about DataBinding and decoupling the business logic and the UI.

Comment: @HighCore This is the point. What is easier for you?

<TextBox>
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="DoubleClick" Command="{Binding YourCommand}" />
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>

or this

<TextBox MouseDoubleClick="TextBox_MouseDoubleClick" />

Comment: How you use MouseDoubleClick in a MVVM app?

Comment: @Guilherme **again**, MVVM **does not care** about mouse stuff, that belongs to the UI. If you want to execute a method from the VM from code behind, that's fine. MVVM is about **separating business logic and UI**. You have a serious misunderstanding of what MVVM is.

Comment: This is a great example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501886/wpf-mvvm-newbie-how-should-the-viewmodel-close-the-form?rq=1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47045/discussion-between-highcore-and-guilherme)

Comment: Maybe you are right, this is what I learn about MVVM. Could you recommend me please a good book or a complete tutorial?

Comment: @Guilherme BTW, yes, an `InputBinding` is really much better than a code behind approach, because: 1 - it takes care of disabling the UI element when `CanExecute()` is false and 2 - you may define many `InputBinding`s to the same `Command` without having to add a bunch of duplicated code behind events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before

```
comboBox_1.Items.Clear();
```

Do

```
comboBox_1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: It's not working, but thanks for your help. The same error message occurs.

Comment: Are you using itemssource?

Comment: If yes, you can erase the Values with some code like this: comboBox_1.ItemsSource = new List<object>();. You will need to test, maybe it works for comboBox_1.ItemsSource = string.Empty;

Comment: Simply change the itemssource to a blank collection.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `Clear()` on the `ComboBox.Items` you should either clear or set to NULL the underlyining collection in your `ViewModel` to which your ComboBox is bound to and which is the data source of your `ComboBox` `Items`...

Comment: Thanks, but the collection cannot be set to NULL. I get the same error message while working with the combobox during runtime, just like selecting an item of the combobox. It stops at once and I get that error message. Annother idea?