# Close a view from a viewmodel in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have seen many examples over the net but I am not able to figure out what i am doing wrong here.
I need to close a view from a view model. Below is the code i have tried:

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public event EventHandler RequestClose;
    public ViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

//Calling the event from view model to close the view from a method in View Model
This event is called on a button click

```
private void Download()
{
//Download Logic
if(RequestClose != null)
                RequestClose(this,EventArgs.Empty);
 }
```

View:

```
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
vm.RequestClose += delegate(object sender, EventArgs args) {this.Close();}
this.DataContext = vm;
```

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: How are you raising this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fire the RequestClose event in the ViewModel constructor which is too early to be catched by the event registration.

Comment: I am calling RequestClose  later from a method in ViewModel, not in the constructor.

Comment: My bad.. I moved the RequestClose event from the constructor. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

The best MVVM solution is to use an attached behavior, as outlined in the top rated answer to this question [How should the ViewModel close the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501886/how-should-the-viewmodel-close-the-form/3329467)

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar problem earlier, and did the following: In the viewmodel, create a command that you can bind to (I personally use MvvmLight and its RelayCommand)

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public RelayCommand<object> CloseWindowCommand {get; private set;}

   public ViewModel()
   {
      CloseWindowCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(CloseTheWindow);
   }

   private void CloseWindow(object obj)
   {
      var window = obj as Window;
      if(window != null) 
         window.Close();
   }
}
```

In my view, I have button that triggers this command, e.g.

```
Button Content="Close" Command="{Binding CloseWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=NameOvViewModel}"
```

I realize now, that this may require the use of MvvmLight, but I hope it offers some guidance on a possible solution to your question.

Comment: -1 Handling `Window`s in the view model breaks the whole MVVM pattern.