# Dependency Property in F#

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm, f#

I have an MVVM app written in F# and one of the main problems which I have faced was closing of modal dialogs. I decided to subscribe to an viewmodel's RequestedClose event in view, but problem of DialogResult still remained. So, I decided to bind DialogResult to viewmodel's property, but soon I realized that DialogResult is not a DependencyProperty. Eventually I tried to implement [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501886/how-should-the-viewmodel-close-the-form/3329467#3329467). But I couldn't get it to work... Here's my code:

```ml
type DialogCloser() =

static let DialogResultProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DialogResult", typeof<bool>, typeof<DialogCloser>)

member this.GetDialogResult (a:DependencyObject) = a.GetValue(DialogResultProperty) :?> bool

member this.SetDialogResult (a:DependencyObject) (value:string) = a.SetValue(DialogResultProperty, value)

member this.DialogResultChanged (a:DependencyObject) (e:DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) =
    let window = a :?> Window
    match window with
    | null -> failwith "Not a Window"
    | _ -> window.DialogResult <- System.Nullable(e.NewValue :?> bool)
```

Also I've tried something like [this](https://stevehorsfield.wordpress.com/2009/08/13/creating-wpf-dependency-properties-in-fsharp/), but it didn't work for me as well. I've faced with two types of exceptions: 1) DialogResult not found in DialogCloser 2) And, if I add DialogResult property with get and set, DialogResult can't be applied to something that is not a DialogCloser.

P.S: I know that there's must be an another way of solving this problem instead of making an Attached Property, but for further development I need to understand how to do this properly in F#.

Comment: If you have followed the example given in your first link (the accepted answer) you need to declare the `GetDialogResult` and `SetDialogResult` methods as `static`. You also forgot to declare the `DialogResultChanged' event handler in the declaration of the `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: @polkduran, oh, I'm so dumb ._. Everything works fine now. I should be more careful... Thanks a lot.