# MVVM's Light INavigationService implementation in WPF (Desktop Apps Best Practices)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

What is the best and clean way to implement this interface in WPF (in your opinion)? I'm talking about your possible experience in desktop applications.

Comment: arguably **possibly primarily opinion-based**

Comment: there you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966819/mvvm-light-5-0-how-to-use-the-navigation-service/28968560#28968560

Comment: You can always port silverlight or wp implementation by copy&pasting it into wpf. Only minor changes to code are required. but IMHO, write your own interface and implementation that perfectly meets your needs. For example, viewmodel first navigation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28916120/475727. There is no reason to stick with some 3rd party interface.