# Binding a main menu command in WPF MVVM application

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I'm developing an WPF app using MVVMLight, and in my main view I have the following:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding WindowClosing}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Which I bind to the following in my view model:

```
public ICommand WindowClosingCommand { get; private set; }

public MainViewModel()
{
 WindowClosingCommand = new RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs>((args) => ExecuteWindowClosingCommand(args));
}

public void ExecuteWindowClosingCommand(CancelEventArgs e)
{
  if (UserSaysNo())
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
  }
}
```

This all works great, and I can display a dialog prompt which allows the user to cancel if required. The problem I have is: how do I bind a 'File->Exit' main menu command to this?

Thanks in advance!
Chris

Comment: In File -> Exit command close the MainWindow, this event will automatically gets called.

Comment: @Ganesh, do you have example code?

Comment: For closing window from VM try this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501886/how-should-the-viewmodel-close-the-form/2100824#2100824