# Silverlight child windows in MVVM pattern

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, mvvm

I am trying to find the right way to get the data from a ChildWindow/popup using a MVVM pattern in Silverlight (3). For example: I have a main page with a data entry form and I want to open a popup with a list of customers. When user selects a customer I want to transfer selected customer into the main page. This is what the (example) code which  I am using at the moment:

**Main page**

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
        DataContext = ViewModel;
    }

    private void SearchCustomer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.SearchCustomer();
    }
}

public class MainPageViewModel: ViewModel
{
    private string customer;
    public string Customer
    {
        get { return customer; }
        set { customer = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Customer"); }
    }

    public void SearchCustomer()
    {
        // Called from a view
        SearchWindow searchWindow = new SearchWindow();
        searchWindow.Closed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if ((bool)searchWindow.DialogResult)
            {
                Customer = searchWindow.ViewModel.SelectedCustomer.ToString();
            }
        };
        searchWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

**Child window**

```
public partial class SearchWindow : ChildWindow
{
    public SearchWindowViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }

    public SearchWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new SearchWindowViewModel();
        DataContext = ViewModel;
    }

    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = ViewModel.OkButtonClick();
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = ViewModel.CancelButtonClick();
    }
}

public class SearchWindowViewModel: ViewModel
{
    private Customer selectedCustomer;        
    private ObservableCollection<Customer> customers;

    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return customers; }
        set {customers = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Customers"); }
    }

    public Customer SelectedCustomer
    {
        get { return selectedCustomer; }
        set { selectedCustomer = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer"); }
    }

    public SearchWindowViewModel()
    {
        Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        ISearchService searchService = new FakeSearchService();
        foreach (Customer customer in searchService.FindCustomers("dummy"))
            Customers.Add(customer);
    }

    public bool? OkButtonClick()
    {
        if (SelectedCustomer != null)
            return true;
        else
            return null; // show some error message before that
    }

    public bool? CancelButtonClick()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is this the right way or is there anything more "simple"?

Cheers,
Rok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More problematic here is the use of View specific terms and types in your VMs.  Click events, DialogResults should not be anywhere near your ViewModels.

With regards to the question, I had a similiar question about this here:
[Handling Dialogs in WPF with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454868/handling-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm)

The answer I accepted was the use of the Mediator pattern to get around this.  Have a look. :)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. I have found out that I'am doing it "completely" wrong and I already changed my code to use commands (binding to ICommand) and remove dialogresult out of the VM. The next step is to look at the Mediator pattern :)

Comment: I agree mediator is the way to go. Blogged about it : http://basaratali.blogspot.com/2010/12/mediator-for-mvvmlight-like-one-by.html

Answer (score 1):

A good MVVM library which supports opening child window is **Chinch mvvm helper library**. You can look at a sample at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SL4FileUploadAnd_SL4_MVVM.aspx.