# Is MVVM pattern broken?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, architecture

I have a WPF-Application based on MVVM-Pattern. All works fine. In the business logic of View-Model I need to invoke some dialogs. I have implemented it through an interface(interface implementation is in a View layer).
For the dialogs I need to set the parent window, so the function in interface has an argument "parentView".

In my ViewModel I have a property "View" from type "object" for a parent window. This property I put as argument for instantiating of a dialog.

Since "View"-property is from type "object" and is set from View layer and forwarded back to the View layer, the View-Model layer has no dependencies on View layer.

What do you think, have I broken the MVVM-Pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do you think, have I broken the MVVM-Pattern?

No. The view model have no dependency upon the view, it only knows about an interface that you could easily mock in your unit tests. So this doesn't really break the pattern as long as "View" is just an abstraction of something.

For type-safety reasons you should probably consider changing the type of the parameter from `object` to a strongly-typed interface type though.

Comment: Thank you for your hint concerned type safety. It is really that I will think about.

Comment: Dependencies between _types_ are class level (low level in terms of architecture) details. On high level application _component_ design (the only concern of MVVM) the pattern is broken. In terms of MVVM the only concern of the view model component is to present the model component (business logic/domain) to the view component acting as an interface, introduced to decouple both components.

Comment: Since a classic application is used by a human, a classic application reflects user stories or use cases which have a goal. Those use cases create input, which is processed by the business logic. The business logic returns a result which is the goal of the user interaction and is actually displayed to the user. The only purpose of the business logic is to serve the user stories. When properly designed, then the view model component should not need to start such an operation like displaying a dialog to interact with the user.

Comment: When designing the application, the view model is not a user and has not a user story: it would never _actively_ ask or wait for user input or trigger the business logic for its own interests (it has no interests as it is a passive presenter/architectural interface). Replacing `Window` with  `IWindow` or `IDialogService` is called Dependency Inversion (a class level pattern or principle e.g., to enable mocking in unit tests) and has nothing to do with MVVM (a component level pattern to decouple components/responsibilities).

Answer (score 1):

No friend - this is a solved problem.
I mean there is no real beauty in all the solutions, but you could use a Dialog-Service for example.

A real easy implementation on this would be a `Singleton` that has a static Field with your Main-`Window`. Now you can call your Dialogs from this class.

I actually think MahApps for example goes like this, but they register it the fancy way:

```
<controls:MetroWindow 
        x:Class="SomeMetroWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        xmlns:Dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Dialog:DialogParticipation.Register="{Binding}"> <!-- watch this pls --->
<!-- ... --->
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

Here is an [example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36745/Showing-Dialogs-When-Using-the-MVVM-Pattern) for general implementation. And here another [arcticle](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dialogs-in-wpf-mvvm/) about arcticles of this topic.

As I said - not really beautiful, but solved.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your answer. Actually it works by me with my variant of dialog service(less code, more flexibility). Put the parent to the singleton is not for me a solution(there are different parents sometimes).

Comment: In general i would not recommend in `WPF` writing your own `DialogService`, because you take a Framework that has that allready the most time. While in Windows-Store-Apps there are allready "native"-Solutions.