# Is it the right way that command parameter references a view control in MVVM pattern?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command

I'm making a page using MVVM pattern.

By the way, I had a question during implementing command.
It is 'Is it the right to send command parameter to UI control'?

For example, I have a TextBox control. When LostFocus event is fired, a validation command binded with TextBox will be raised and I will send an UI control as command parameter to display a validation failure message.

After a command is executed, I will change content value of UI control if validate is failed.

These are my scenario.

But I know a viewmodel should not reference any of views and its controls directly.

Please let me know how.

Comment: For validation you can use "IDataErrorInfo" or "INotifyDataErrorInfo" interface. These interefaces works well with MVVM patten. Please have a look at this tutorial about same : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_validations.htm

Comment: You can take a look to my question, may be it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931775/is-mvvm-pattern-broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your validation is evaluated in the code behind of your view/control then you are fine to send or pass a control.

I have to question what sort of validation is being done at the UI layer - it can be general input logic (like numbers only or only certain letters, etc), but it shouldn't involve any business logic. Your code behind *could* call a method on the viewmodel to perform business logic based validation, but it should avoid passing a control.

If you are simply looking for a way to make a generic validation method for multiple controls, then you should consider another way such as:

- creating a custom usercontrol that has the validation
- using an attached behavior

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer.

Answer (score 1):

A view model should not have any references or any dependencies upon any UI control such as a `TextBox`.

Instead of passing a reference to the `TextBox` as a command parameter to the view model command, you should either pass the value of the `Text` property of the `TextBox` as a `string` argument or - even better - you should simply bind the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to a `string` source property of the view model:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding YourViewModelProperty}" />
```

The source property will be set when the `TextBox` loses focus and you can easily kick off your validation logic in the setter:

```
private string _s;
public string YourViewModelProperty
{
    get { return _s; }
    set { _s = value; Validate(); }
}
```

This is how the MVVM pattern is supposed to be implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer.