# How to instance a child Window in WPF that takes parameters from the main Window, but respects MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have implemented something violating the MVVM pattern, and I wondered if there was a MVVM way of doing this.

I have a Window `MainWindow`, its DataContext is bound to a class called `ViewModel` which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I also implemented a Window `ChildWindow` which appears in a "Dialog" style when a button is clicked, using a `RelayCommand`. The DataContext of `ChildWindow` also binds to `ViewModel`. This Window is used to fill the details of a new list Item. I pass the View as a `CommandParameter` to the `ViewModel`, so that the `ChildWindow` can be centered in comparison to the `MainWindow`. This is not MVVM, and I would like to change this.

First, I implemented this in a non-MVVM way: 
Here is my XAML for the button in `MainWindow` which opens the `ChildWindow`:

```
 <Button Name="BtnInsert" Width="50" Margin="10" Command="{Binding OpenChildWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">Add</Button>
```

Here is my simplified XAML for the ChildWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="HWE_Einteilen_Prototype.View.ListItemWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HWE_Einteilen_Prototype.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="test" Height="400" Width="400">
    <TextBox Width="50" Text="{Binding CurrentListItem.Id}" ></TextBox>
</Window>
```

And here is my (simplified) ViewModel Class:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DataContext _ctx;
    private ListItem _currentListItem;
    private ObservableCollection<listItem> _listItems;

    private ListItemWindow _listItemWindow;
    private ICommand _openListItemWindowCommand;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<ListItem> ListItems
    {
        get { return _listItems; }
        set
        {
            _listItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ListItem CurrentListItem
    {
        get { return _currentListItem; }
        set
        {
            _currentListItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand OpenListItemWindowCommand
    {
        get { return _openListItemWindowCommand; }
        set
        {
            _openListItemWindowCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        OpenListItemWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(this.OpenNewListItemWindow, this.CanOpenListItemWindow);
    }

    private void OpenNewListItemWindow(object parameter) 
    {
        CurrentListItem = new listItem(){Id = "testId"};
        _listItemWindow = new StListItemWindow(){DataContext = this};     
        _listItemWindow.Owner = (MainWindow)parameter;                   
        _listItemWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        _listItemWindow.Closing += OnStListItemWindowClosing;    
        _listItemWindow.Show();
    }

    private bool CanOpenListItemWindow(object parameter) 
    {
        return true;
    }


    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**What I have tried:** 
I have tried implementing a Behavior (from system.windows.interactivity) for the button opening the child window, so that it creates a new Window and does all the centering and owner stuff, and leaving only  `CurrentListItem = new listItem(){Id = "testId"};` in the command method. However, in this case binding to CurrentListItem in the ChildWindow throws an exception.

XAML Code for the `MainWindow` Button:

```
    <Button Name="BtnInsert" Width="50" Margin="10" Command="{Binding OpenListItemWindowCommand}" Content="Add">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:BehButtonNewWindow></behaviors:BehButtonNewWindow>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Button>
```

Behavior Code:

```
class BehButtonNewWindow : Behavior<Button>
{
    private StListItemWindow _ListItemWindow;
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Click += OnClickHandler;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Click -= OnClickHandler;
    }
    private void OnClickHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        if (sender is Button button)
        {
            var win = Window.GetWindow(button);

            if (win != null)
            {
                _ListItemWindow = new ListItemWindow
                {
                    DataContext = win.DataContext,
                    Owner = win,
                    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner
                };

                _ListItemWindow.Show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Code of Command Execute Method from ViewModel:

```
    private void OpenNewStListItemWindow(object parameter) 
    {
        CurrentListItem = new ListItem(){Id = "testId"}; 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening new window in MVVM WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845689/opening-new-window-in-mvvm-wpf)

Comment: Concerning mvvm violation - you can take a look to the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931775/is-mvvm-pattern-broken

Comment: @Sinatr it's not a duplicate. The question you linked to is concerned with creating a new Window for a new ViewModel instance. The question I have is creating a new Window binding to the SAME ViewModel instance.

Comment: But it is still creating new window with some sort of ViewModel attached to said window.

Comment: Opening a window is a UI concern. Simply handle the button click in the codebehind, construct a new window and stick the current VM in it. MVVM != no codebehind.

Comment: @Will OK - I am open to your suggestion. But then, how do I handle the changes in the VM that also have to occur with this button click?

Comment: I don't know what changes you need in the vm, so I can't say.

Comment: @Will adding a new Item to an ObservableCollection in the VM, which is implemented as a Property. Like in the example I've posted.

Comment: You may be familiar with it, but I'm not. And there's a lot of code, so I don't want to spend a lot of time trying to figure out what you're vaguely referencing. If you mean that last little bit of code at the bottom, make it public and have the window call it before opening the new window. The UI is perfectly fine knowing about your view models. They're designed to display their state and bind to their properties.

Comment: @Will  I was just referencing to my post for further information. 
Anyhow, thanks for providing that simple solution! I guess after reading so much about this issues, I got pretty confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit for this answer goes to Will (see comments)

On handling the window opening:

> Opening a window is a UI concern. Simply handle the button click in the codebehind, construct a new window and stick the current VM in it. MVVM != no codebehind.

On handling vm code:

> [...] If you mean that last little bit of code at the bottom, make it public and have the window call it before opening the new window. The UI is perfectly fine knowing about your view models. They're designed to display their state and bind to their properties.

Thanks for your help!