# How to set owner for dialog opened from a view model?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a parent view which shows a grid. In one of the columns there is a button on every row to show a child dialog to edit the object that each row of the grid is bound to. The button is bound to a command on the view model which shows the dialog. I use `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` to pass a reference to object to edit to the view model of the child dialog.

I want to the dialog to be centered relative to the window it opened from which I can do with  `dialog.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner` but I need a reference to the parent window.

I can think of two solutions but I don't think either of them is clean.

1. If I wasn't using the command parameter already I could pass the window to parent view model like this `CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"`. I could use a multi binding and a converter to pass two parameters but is this good practice? I tend to think the view model shouldn't know any thing about views.
2. I can pass a reference to the parent window that host the parent view to it's view model in the view model's constructor. Again what I don't like is that the view model knows about windows which seems like a dependency in the wrong direction.

What I also don't like about either of these approaches is the parent view model needs to have knowledge of the child window it is creating.

I saw[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845689/opening-new-window-in-mvvm-wpf) answer which shows how to use a service that the view model can use to open a window without having any knowledge of the window its creating which is great but I kind think of a clean way to pass the parent window without going through the view model.

Comment: Sometime I just access the parent main window like this :                                         'var mainWindow=System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;'

Comment: This can be helpful for you [Q: Is MVVM pattern broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42931775/7713750). See also [A: Open File Dialog MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43756154/7713750)

Comment: You could use `Popup` instead of a seperate dialog as it is easier to control from a 'parent' and centers on the parent by default.