# Good or bad practice for Dialogs in wpf with MVVM?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, modal-dialog

I lately had the problem of creating add and edit dialogs for my wpf app.

All I want to do in my code was something like this. (I mostly use viewmodel first approach with mvvm)

ViewModel which calls a dialog window:

```
var result = this.uiDialogService.ShowDialog("Dialogwindow Title", dialogwindowVM);
// Do anything with the dialog result
```

How does it work?

First, I created a dialog service:

```
public interface IUIWindowDialogService
{
    bool? ShowDialog(string title, object datacontext);
}

public class WpfUIWindowDialogService : IUIWindowDialogService
{
    public bool? ShowDialog(string title, object datacontext)
    {
        var win = new WindowDialog();
        win.Title = title;
        win.DataContext = datacontext;

        return win.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

`WindowDialog` is a special but simple window.  I need it to hold my content:

```
<Window x:Class="WindowDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    Title="WindowDialog" 
    WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="DialogPresenter" Content="{Binding .}">

    </ContentPresenter>
</Window>
```

A problem with dialogs in wpf is the `dialogresult = true` can only be achieved in code.  That's why I created an interface for my `dialogviewmodel` to implement it.

```
public class RequestCloseDialogEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool DialogResult { get; set; }
    public RequestCloseDialogEventArgs(bool dialogresult)
    {
        this.DialogResult = dialogresult;
    }
}

public interface IDialogResultVMHelper
{
    event EventHandler<RequestCloseDialogEventArgs> RequestCloseDialog;
}
```

Whenever my ViewModel thinks it's time for `dialogresult = true`, then raise this event.

```
public partial class DialogWindow : Window
{
    // Note: If the window is closed, it has no DialogResult
    private bool _isClosed = false;

    public DialogWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DialogPresenter.DataContextChanged += DialogPresenterDataContextChanged;
        this.Closed += DialogWindowClosed;
    }

    void DialogWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this._isClosed = true;
    }

    private void DialogPresenterDataContextChanged(object sender,
                              DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var d = e.NewValue as IDialogResultVMHelper;

        if (d == null)
            return;

        d.RequestCloseDialog += new EventHandler<RequestCloseDialogEventArgs>
                                    (DialogResultTrueEvent).MakeWeak(
                                        eh => d.RequestCloseDialog -= eh;);
    }

    private void DialogResultTrueEvent(object sender, 
                              RequestCloseDialogEventArgs eventargs)
    {
        // Important: Do not set DialogResult for a closed window
        // GC clears windows anyways and with MakeWeak it
        // closes out with IDialogResultVMHelper
        if(_isClosed) return;

        this.DialogResult = eventargs.DialogResult;
    }
 }
```

Now at least I have to create a `DataTemplate` in my resource file(`app.xaml` or something):

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DialogViewModel:EditOrNewAuswahlItemVM}" >
        <DialogView:EditOrNewAuswahlItem/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Well thats all, I can now call dialogs from my viewmodels:

```
 var result = this.uiDialogService.ShowDialog("Dialogwindow Title", dialogwindowVM);
```

Now my question, do you see any problems with this solution?

Edit: for completeness. The ViewModel should implement `IDialogResultVMHelper` and then it can raise it within a `OkCommand` or something like this:

```
public class MyViewmodel : IDialogResultVMHelper
{
    private readonly Lazy<DelegateCommand> _okCommand;

    public MyViewmodel()
    {
         this._okCommand = new Lazy<DelegateCommand>(() => 
             new DelegateCommand(() => 
                 InvokeRequestCloseDialog(
                     new RequestCloseDialogEventArgs(true)), () => 
                         YourConditionsGoesHere = true));
    }

    public ICommand OkCommand
    { 
        get { return this._okCommand.Value; } 
    }

    public event EventHandler<RequestCloseDialogEventArgs> RequestCloseDialog;
    private void InvokeRequestCloseDialog(RequestCloseDialogEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = RequestCloseDialog;
        if (handler != null) 
            handler(this, e);
    }
 }
```

EDIT 2: I used the code from here to make my EventHandler register weak:
http://diditwith.net/2007/03/23/SolvingTheProblemWithEventsWeakEventHandlers.aspx
(Website no longer exists, [WebArchive Mirror](http://web.archive.org/web/20140319163345/http://diditwith.net/2007/03/23/SolvingTheProblemWithEventsWeakEventHandlers.aspx))

```
public delegate void UnregisterCallback<TE>(EventHandler<TE> eventHandler) 
    where TE : EventArgs;

public interface IWeakEventHandler<TE> 
    where TE : EventArgs
{
    EventHandler<TE> Handler { get; }
}

public class WeakEventHandler<T, TE> : IWeakEventHandler<TE> 
    where T : class 
    where TE : EventArgs
{
    private delegate void OpenEventHandler(T @this, object sender, TE e);

    private readonly WeakReference mTargetRef;
    private readonly OpenEventHandler mOpenHandler;
    private readonly EventHandler<TE> mHandler;
    private UnregisterCallback<TE> mUnregister;

    public WeakEventHandler(EventHandler<TE> eventHandler,
                                UnregisterCallback<TE> unregister)
    {
        mTargetRef = new WeakReference(eventHandler.Target);

        mOpenHandler = (OpenEventHandler)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                           typeof(OpenEventHandler),null, eventHandler.Method);

        mHandler = Invoke;
        mUnregister = unregister;
    }

    public void Invoke(object sender, TE e)
    {
        T target = (T)mTargetRef.Target;

        if (target != null)
            mOpenHandler.Invoke(target, sender, e);
        else if (mUnregister != null)
        {
            mUnregister(mHandler);
            mUnregister = null;
        }
    }

    public EventHandler<TE> Handler
    {
        get { return mHandler; }
    }

    public static implicit operator EventHandler<TE>(WeakEventHandler<T, TE> weh)
    {
        return weh.mHandler;
    }
}

public static class EventHandlerUtils
{
    public static EventHandler<TE> MakeWeak<TE>(this EventHandler<TE> eventHandler, 
                                                    UnregisterCallback<TE> unregister)
        where TE : EventArgs
    {
        if (eventHandler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("eventHandler");

        if (eventHandler.Method.IsStatic || eventHandler.Target == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Only instance methods are supported.",
                                            "eventHandler");

        var wehType = typeof(WeakEventHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(
                          eventHandler.Method.DeclaringType, typeof(TE));

        var wehConstructor = wehType.GetConstructor(new Type[] 
                             { 
                                 typeof(EventHandler<TE>), typeof(UnregisterCallback<TE>) 
                             });

        IWeakEventHandler<TE> weh = (IWeakEventHandler<TE>)wehConstructor.Invoke(
                                        new object[] { eventHandler, unregister });

        return weh.Handler;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are probably missing the xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" refernece in your WindowDialog XAML.

Comment: Actually the namespace is         xmlns:x="[http://]schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" without the brackets

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993433/mvvm-light-wpf-binding-multiple-instances-of-a-window-to-a-viewmodel/16994523#16994523

Comment: Hi @blindmeis. I know that almost 5 years passed, but I stuck at closing the dialog part. Can you please explain that part?

Comment: your viewmodel has to implement IDialogResultVMHelper and raise the event of course. see my edit

Comment: @blindmeis thank you for your response. I already implemented that interface. My problem was that I also setted data context in the xaml of my user control. as  <UserControl.DataContext> </UserControl.DataContext>. Because of it, at the InitializeComponenet() part new instance of that class was created so event was removed. After one day stuck I removed setting data context from xaml and it works like a charm. Thanks for a great post. It is very helpful.

Comment: i always use viewmodel first approach with DataTemplates in my applications except within the mainwindow. so i dont need UserControl.DataContext in any of my views :)

Comment: Hi! Latecomer here.

I'm not understanding how your Service has a reference to the WindowDialog. What's the hierarchy of your models?

In my mind, the View holds a reference to the Viewmodel assembly and the Viewmodel to the Service and Model assemblies. Thereby, the Service layer would have no knowledge of the WindowDialog view. What am I missing?

Comment: This might be better posted in codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi @blindmeis, just trying to wrap my head around this concept, I don't suppose there's some online example project I can pick over? There's a number of things I'm confused about.

Comment: Sorry, but where is an instance of object of DialogService located and how is it transmitted to ViewModel of callers?

Comment: i use DependencyInjection to get an Instance of IUIWindowDialogService.

Comment: @Moe45673 Obviously, the WindowDialog cannot be in the same assembly as the rest of the application's view, so as not to create circular dependencies. You would also want it to be in a different assembly to reuse it in other applications.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is a good approach and I used similar ones in the past. Go for it!

One minor thing I'd definitely do is make the event receive a boolean for when you need to set "false" in the DialogResult.

```
event EventHandler<RequestCloseEventArgs> RequestCloseDialog;
```

and the EventArgs class:

```
public class RequestCloseEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public RequestCloseEventArgs(bool dialogResult)
    {
        this.DialogResult = dialogResult;
    }

    public bool DialogResult { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: What if instead of using services, one uses a sort of Callback to facilitate interaction with the ViewModel and the View? For example, View executes a Command in the ViewModel, then when all is said and done, the ViewModel fires a Callback for the View to display the results of the Command. I still can't get my team onboard with using Services to handle Dialog interactions in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 16):

I've been using an almost identical approach for several months now, and I'm very happy with it (i.e. I haven't yet felt the urge to rewrite it completely...)

In my implementation, I use a `IDialogViewModel` that exposes things such as the title, the standad buttons to show (in order to have a consistent apparence across all dialogs), a `RequestClose` event, and a few other things to be able to control the window size and behavior

Comment: thx, the title should really go in my IDialogViewModel. the other properties like size, standard button i will leave, because this all comes from the datatemplate at least.

Comment: That's what I did at first too, just use SizeToContent to control the size of the window. But in one case I needed to make the window resizable, so I had to tweak it a little...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque the buttons contained in your ViewModel, are they actually UI Button objects or objects representing buttons?

Comment: @Thomas, objects representing buttons. You should never reference UI objects in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about dialogue windows and not just about the pop-up message boxes, please consider my approach below. The key points are:

1. I pass a reference to `Module Controller` into the constructor of each `ViewModel` (you can use injection).
2. That `Module Controller` has public/internal methods for creating dialogue windows (just creating, without returning a result). Hence to open a dialogue window in `ViewModel` I write: `controller.OpenDialogEntity(bla, bla...)`
3. Each dialogue window notifies about its result (like *OK*, *Save*, *Cancel*, etc.) via [Weak Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx). If you use PRISM, then it's easier to publish notifications using [this EventAggregator](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/).
4. To handle dialogue results, I'm using subscription to notifications (again [Weak Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) and [EventAggregator](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/) in case of PRISM). To reduce dependency on such notifications, use independent classes with standard notifications.

**Pros:**

- Less code. I don't mind using interfaces, but I've seen too many projects where excessiveness of using interfaces and abstraction layers cause more trouble than help.
- Open dialogue windows through `Module Controller` is a simple way to avoid strong references and still allows to use mock-ups for testing.
- Notification through weak events reduce number of potential memory leaks.

**Cons:**

- Not easy to distinguish required notification from others in the handler. Two solutions:

  - send a unique token on opening a dialogue window and check that token in the subscription
  - use generic notification classes `<T>` where `T` is enumeration of entities (or for simplicity it can be type of ViewModel).
- For a project should be an agreement about using notification classes to prevent duplicating them.
- For enormously large projects the `Module Controller` can be overwhelmed by methods for creating windows. In this case it's better to split it up in several modules.

P.S. I have been using this approach for quite a long time now and ready to defend its eligibility in comments and provide some examples if required.