# Using MVVM Foundation Messenger to Show Dialog

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-foundation

i have read the other question here on StackOverflow. I understand how to create messages between ViewModels/Objects. But I dont get how can i actually display a dialog. Can I see some code samples implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a mediator or messenger to communicate between viewmodels has nothing to do with the mvvm dialog problem.
here is the way i show [dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practise-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm).

Comment: so i just use a service to open dialogs eg. SaveFileDialog, OpenFileDialog or MessageBoxes?

Comment: correct :) the link i posted is for dialogs in general. for dialogs like SaveFileDialog, OpenFileDialog or MessageBoxes i use concrete services like WpfMessageboxService and so on. take a look at the cinch project http://cinch.codeplex.com/, there i get some really good stuff for mvvm.