# WPF : customised Messge box to use in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, messagebox

I know that we can't use messageBox in xaml. But..Can we have a custome "Message box user control"...with a view model..which is having following properties : Message, Trigger (to popup), Icon ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure you can do this. just create a window(maybe a viewmodel too if needed) with stuff and properties you want your messagebox look like. then create a ICustomMessageBoxService interface and implementation which you can use in your viewmodels to show your CustomMessageBox.

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practise-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm). there is an example for a custom dialog service. you can easily customize it for your messageboxservice.