# MVVM Invoke Method in View (from ControlTemplate via ViewModel)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, controltemplate

I would like to know how the following problem can be solved WITHOUT using Event Aggregation. This is for WPF 3.5 SP1, so the CallMethodBehavior is not available.

Simple Scenario: A click on a button inside a ControlTemplate needs to be triggered to the VM. I used CaliburnMicro's ActionMessage which worked fine. Inside the ViewModel I want to trigger a method inside the View, which only starts a custom transition (no real logic). I tried many things, but I did not work out.

I created a Property in my view, which could call the method but I am not able to use Triggers to set a new value for the property, because I can't tell the setter to target a property outside the controltemplate.

So in essence I want to update a Property in the viewmodel and trigger a set-property in the view class. Or if you have any idea how to get around this at all: I am open to new ideas! :D

Regards
Gope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution I can live with: I ported the CallMethodAction to 3.5 and wrote my own PropertyChangedTrigger. It's pretty simple to call a method inside the view via a PropertyChange in the viewmodel - Kids: don't try this at home. It's only for special scenarios! :D

Find my code below:

usage:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

<i:Interaction.Triggers >         
    <Framework:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding StartTransition}" Value="True">
        <Framework:CallMethodAction MethodName="ApplyTransition" />
    </Framework:PropertyChangedTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

PropertyChangedTrigger:

```
public class PropertyChangedTrigger : TriggerBase<DependencyObject>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Binding", typeof(object), typeof(PropertyChangedTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnBindingChanged)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(PropertyChangedTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object Binding
    {
        get
        {
            return base.GetValue(BindingProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(BindingProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return base.GetValue(ValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void EvaluateBindingChange(object args)
    {
        var propertyChangedArgs = (DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)args;
        string newValue = propertyChangedArgs.NewValue.ToString();
        bool equal = string.Equals(newValue, Value.ToString(),StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if(equal)
        {
            InvokeActions(args);
        }
    }

    private static void OnBindingChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        ((PropertyChangedTrigger)sender).EvaluateBindingChange(args);
    }
}
```

CallMethodAction:

```
 public class CallMethodAction : TargetedTriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
{
    private List<MethodDescriptor> methodDescriptors = new List<MethodDescriptor>();
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MethodNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MethodName", typeof(string), typeof(CallMethodAction), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMethodNameChanged)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TargetObject", typeof(object), typeof(CallMethodAction), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTargetObjectChanged)));

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.UpdateMethodInfo();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        this.methodDescriptors.Clear();
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private static void OnMethodNameChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        ((CallMethodAction)sender).UpdateMethodInfo();
    }

    private static void OnTargetObjectChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        ((CallMethodAction)sender).UpdateMethodInfo();
    }

    private static bool AreMethodParamsValid(ParameterInfo[] methodParams)
    {
        if (methodParams.Length == 2)
        {
            if (methodParams[0].ParameterType != typeof(object))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (!typeof(EventArgs).IsAssignableFrom(methodParams[1].ParameterType))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (methodParams.Length != 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        if (base.AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            MethodDescriptor descriptor = this.FindBestMethod(parameter);
            if (descriptor != null)
            {
                ParameterInfo[] parameters = descriptor.Parameters;
                if (parameters.Length == 0)
                {
                    descriptor.MethodInfo.Invoke(this.Target, null);
                }
                else if ((((parameters.Length == 2) && (base.AssociatedObject != null)) && ((parameter != null) && parameters[0].ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(base.AssociatedObject.GetType()))) && parameters[1].ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(parameter.GetType()))
                {
                    descriptor.MethodInfo.Invoke(this.Target, new object[] { base.AssociatedObject, parameter });
                }
            }
            else if (this.TargetObject != null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "No valid method found.", new object[] { this.MethodName, this.TargetObject.GetType().Name }));
            }
        }
    }

    private MethodDescriptor FindBestMethod(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            parameter.GetType();
        }
        return this.methodDescriptors.FirstOrDefault(methodDescriptor => (!methodDescriptor.HasParameters || ((parameter != null) && methodDescriptor.SecondParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(parameter.GetType()))));
    }

    private void UpdateMethodInfo()
    {
        this.methodDescriptors.Clear();
        if ((this.Target != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.MethodName))
        {
            foreach (MethodInfo info in this.Target.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
            {
                if (this.IsMethodValid(info))
                {
                    ParameterInfo[] parameters = info.GetParameters();
                    if (AreMethodParamsValid(parameters))
                    {
                        this.methodDescriptors.Add(new MethodDescriptor(info, parameters));
                    }
                }
            }
            this.methodDescriptors = this.methodDescriptors.OrderByDescending<MethodDescriptor, int>(delegate(MethodDescriptor methodDescriptor)
            {
                int num = 0;
                if (methodDescriptor.HasParameters)
                {
                    for (Type type = methodDescriptor.SecondParameterType; type != typeof(EventArgs); type = type.BaseType)
                    {
                        num++;
                    }
                }
                return (methodDescriptor.ParameterCount + num);
            }).ToList<MethodDescriptor>();
        }
    }


    private bool IsMethodValid(MethodInfo method)
    {
        if (!string.Equals(method.Name, this.MethodName, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (method.ReturnType != typeof(void))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void InvokeInternal()
    {
        if (AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            foreach (
                MethodInfo info in AssociatedObject.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
            {
                if (IsMethodValid(info))
                {
                    info.Invoke(AssociatedObject, new object[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }





    public string MethodName
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base.GetValue(MethodNameProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(MethodNameProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private object Target
    {
        get
        {
            return (TargetObject ?? base.AssociatedObject);
        }
    }

    public object TargetObject
    {
        get
        {
            return base.GetValue(TargetObjectProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(TargetObjectProperty, value);
        }
    }





    private class MethodDescriptor
    {
        public MethodDescriptor(MethodInfo methodInfo, ParameterInfo[] methodParams)
        {
            MethodInfo = methodInfo;
            Parameters = methodParams;
        }

        public bool HasParameters
        {
            get
            {
                return (Parameters.Length > 0);
            }
        }

        public MethodInfo MethodInfo { get; private set; }

        public int ParameterCount
        {
            get
            {
                return Parameters.Length;
            }
        }

        public ParameterInfo[] Parameters { get; private set; }

        public Type SecondParameterType
        {
            get
            {
                if (Parameters.Length >= 2)
                {
                    return Parameters[1].ParameterType;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps anybode. All questions are welcome! Remeber: all this can be found in the Expression Blend SDK 4. This code is only for people who are forced to work with older versions like 3.5

Regards
Gope
Gope

Comment: Hello Gope, I would like to do tests with this code snippet. Unfortunately it is not complete. FirtsOrDefault and OrderByDescending methods are not defined in class MethodDescriptor. Could you please add this code? Edit:
Oops, methodDescriptor is of type List<T>, so this methods comes from List<T>.
using System.Linq was missing.

Answer (score 1):

i think the most simple way is to expose an event from your vm and subscribe to it in your view?
i used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practise-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm) for dialogs to send DialogResult from vm

Comment: That is indeed an idea, although I try to keep the Code-Behind to a minimum. What I don't like about it is that you shouldn't have any references to the viewmodel, meaning to cast the DataContext, which I am not to fond of either, but actually your suggestion would work and is simple, which makes it charming. :D
I found another possible solution which I post below.

Best regards and thanks for taking your time to answer my question!