# WPF Command and exception in ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

button has a `Command` binding into `ViewModel` (it runs some `Save` method in ViewModel). Method `Save` can fail and throw an exception.

What is a best practice how to catch those exceptions? It would suffice to show a `MessageBox` but I do not want to do it in `ViewModel` (this is not the right way).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1 - I don't believe it's "not the right way".

Having an `Exception` raised in `ViewModel` is typically part of the `ViewModel` logic. Therefore, showing a `MessageBox` there wouldn't be "the bad way".
Keep in mind that the actual aim of MVVM is **NOT** to eliminate ALL code-behind, but is actually to clearly separate UI-logic and business-logic. An exception will happen when dealing with business objects -- you can handle it in the `ViewModel`

2 - Anyway if you want to stick with this approach (I'd qualify it as an extremist MVVM - heh -) you could:

- Use a validator (have you heard about `Binding.ValidationRules` ? if not, [this article should be useful for you](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx) ) to ensure data entered won't create an `Exception`
- Define a specific return value if an `Exception` happens, ie. try-catch, and if you ever happen to enter in catch, you'll return a specific Error value which will be treated by UI as an error (you could for example use a `Trigger` to color the field in red if this specific error value has been returned)

Anyway again I think that there are a lot of people who want to apply an "extremist MVVM" by eliminating all possible code-behind and introducing complex patterns (Attached Behaviors for example...) just to follow a requirement which is actually nonsense in my opinion. I won't say I'm absolutely right, but I prefer to see MVVM as a pattern which will simplify my way of coding than a pattern which will introduce me so much pain for basic things (for example I've seen people implementing AttachedBehaviors for a simple DoubleClick action. I personally add an EventHandler firing the DoubleClick command to my MVVM when the DoubleClick event is fired. 1 line of code against a 100-lines class + XAML code for the other approach, choose your side. I believe that a simple problem should have a simple solution)

Cheers!

Comment: How can you automatically test your `ViewModel` if there is Message Box showing?

Comment: eliminating code-behind is not the purpose of MVVM. It's to remove business logic from the view so you can test it

Answer (score 8):

why you think its not the right way to show a messagebox? cause of unit test for the viewmodel? if thats your problem just write a IMessageBoxService which you use in your vm.

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practise-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm) shows how to create a dialog service. so you have to improve it a little bit to get the messageboxservice you want.