# Issue with opening Child window from Main window using WPF with MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I am learning WPF with M-V-VM. And I am using `ICommand`, `RelayCommand`.
I have several Views, Models, and ViewModels. 
The MainWIndowView open upon on application start. The MainWindowView has a button that opens another WPF window called “FileListview” via MainWindowViewModel.
The FileListView has a button “View Lookup”, which supposed to open another WPF window called “LookupView” via FileListViewModel. But I could not make this button to work unless I specify FileListView in App.xaml.cs  instead of MainWIndowView. I could not understand why “View Lookup” button work if I make application to start from “FileListView” . I also don’t understand whether I need model for MainWindowView, and FileListView since I don’t have anything going except one view’s button is opening another view.
On code behind file “App.xaml.cs” I have

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnStartup(e);
      WPFProject. MainWIndowView window = new MainWIndowView ();
      MainWIndowViewModel  VM = new MainWIndowViewModel ();
      window.DataContext = VM;
      window.Show();
    }
 }
```

I would appreciate if somebody can point me to good article or sample code using WPF with M-V-VM that reflect my issue.

Comment: 1) Show code which open FileListview by a button click; 
2) Show how you bind ViewModel to LookupView; 
3) Show how you bind ViewModel to FileListview;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rethinking the issue, I was able to figure out the solution. 
**The cause of the issue: I was not associating View with it’s ViewModel class.**
So I put the following code in code behind of FileListView.xaml.cs.

```
public partial class FileListView: Window
{
  private FileListViewModel  _ fileListViewModel = new FileListViewModel ();
  public FileListViewModel () 
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    base.DataContext = _fileListViewModel; 
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practise-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm) is my approach to use dialogs/child windows with mvvm and wpf. please note the comment from sllev and post all relevant code.

Comment: I demonstrate a similar approach in my book.