# Show a dialog box with a description

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, user-experience, dialog

The Microsoft's [User Experience Interaction Guidelines for Windows 7 and Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511258.aspx) suggests creating dialog boxes with a *title,* the *main instructions* and a *context*. For example:

[image]

But... the method `Show` of the class [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx) accepts, at most, a text (=main instructions) and a caption (=title).

How can I create a dialog box like the one above with a large blue text for the main instructions and a small black text for the context?

I'm using C# with .NET 4 and WPF.

Comment: What is your requirement ? Dialog box is quite different from a MessageBox. A MessageBox just for prompting the user with a simple message with an appropriate icon,description etc... You cannot do what you're trying to do on a MessageBox

Comment: Hello! I would like to create a dialog box identical to that shown above. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a [`TaskDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which was introduced in Windows Vista. See [this for an example](http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/2011/06/30/how-to-use-taskdialog-api-in-c/) of how to use it. If you call it on an earlier version of Windows, it'll fail. You should check the OS version yourself, and call `MessageBox` in that case.

Comment: Great, thank you! The article you linked said that the _"Only limitation of Task Dialog API is it doesn’t supported by Windows operating systems less than Windows Vista"._ But does it means that I have to check the current version of the operating system and if < Windows Vista I have to use the old `MessageBox`? Or is it automatic?

Answer (score 1):

you can check the messagbox from [here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/).

and taskdialog from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30649/A-Customizable-WPF-TaskDialog).

or simply built the messagebox you want. how dialogs are done with mvvm goes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practise-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm).

Answer (score 0):

[OOkii.Dialogs](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/) is a nice little free library that takes the pain out of a whole range of dialogs for WPF including handling dropping back to older dialogs on OSs that dont support new ones.