# how to make successful login close LoginView in WPF MVVM application?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, autowired

I have a WPF application in MVVM architecture.
When the application loads I need to show a 'Login' window where the user inputs username and password.

This is then passed to a ServiceLocator, which creates a client that connects to the WCF service.

Question :

How do I make the 'Login' window close once the client has successfully connected, without using any code-behind in the View's *'.cs'* file ?

Comment: Hide the main window. Show it in case of successful login. Login window should be handled as any other dialog in MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

I normally pass the ViewModel a Close Action in the IDialogService implementation.

```
public void ShowDialog(IDialogViewModel vm)
{
    // create the dialog view
    ...
    vm.CloseAction = () => dialog.Close();
    dialog.DataContext = vm;
    ...
    // show the dialog 
    dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a [dialogservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practise-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm) for my login and expose an event

```
event EventHandler<RequestCloseEventArgs> RequestCloseDialog;
```

which closes the dialog when the client succesfully looged in.

edit: Here's an example

In your `app.xaml.cs`

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var result = this._dialogService.Show("Login",this._myloginviewmodel);

    // When use click cancel in the login dialog
    if(!result)
    { 
        // Close app or whatever
    }

    // Access the properties of myloginviewmodel if you want

    // Now the only part of my app where I use view-first instead of viewmodel-first
    this.MainWindow = new MainWindow(_mainwindowviwemodel);
    this.MainWindow.Show();
}
```

That's all in my `OnStartup()`, and yes thats the codebehind from my `app.xaml`, but this is my application root and thats why this is ok for me. I don't have a AppViewModel or something like that because `app.xaml` will never "shown" to the user.

Comment: how do you use it in the 'OnStartup' ? can you please post a code sample ?

Comment: and like @pchajer said : doesn't this violate the MVVM as the logic are written in code behind which is against the MVVM ?

Comment: no, because i have no viewmodel with a reference to the view. and the app.xaml.cs its not a "view codebehind" for me - its my application root.

Answer (score 0):

You can override OnStartup method of Application class, where you can open the Login screen as a dialog, once user enter valid data you can return boolean value, on closing of login screen, you can do your further logic based on the boolean value.