# MVVM, use new Windows or Views?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

After finishing some by-hand projects, my recent project implements the MVVM pattern using Caliburn.Micro - but I still struggle with some architectural problems. Mainly:

My ViewModel contains a `BindableCollection` `ProfilesCollection` of `Profiles`. My view has a button to add new profiles. But since the profiles are complex I want the button click to open a new window where I can fill in the details, and then return back to the main window.

In my previous by hand approach I made the `ProfilesCollection` static so that it was accessible throughout the whole application, and as click event I just opened a new window, where I then stored the new profile in the static `Collection`.

What would be the right MVVM approach? Create a new view/ viewmodel instead of a new window? How do I manage them, and how do I pass the `Profile` I create back to the MainViewModel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would start by passing the `ProfilesCollection` into a `ProfilesViewModel` along with a `ProfilesView` for selecting the profile you want to edit and for adding/removing profiles.

Second, I would have a separate `ProfileViewModel` and `ProfileView`. The `ProfileViewModel` would have a `ShowDialog` method that would call `ShowDialog` on the `ProfileView` child window. This will allow the `ProfilesViewModel` to set the profile on the `ProfileViewModel` and then call `ShowDialog`, which will fit the MVVM pattern nicely.

For more information on this, check out the [Wpf Application Framework](http://waf.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

you can simply open a new dialog/window to fill your details. check out my apporach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practise-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm)