# Does you know a MVVM Framework where support DialogService?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dialog, prism

I'm working right now with Prism in a  WPF Application. But now I feel the necessity to use a `DialogService`, and I would like to use a MVVM Framework where support this feature.

I wouldn't like to implement my own `DialogService.`
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If by `DialogService` you mean a way to open windows from ViewModel without poluting it with code from View layer, there is [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) project. It delivers IWindowManager with standard implementation in form of WindowManager class. It has `ShowWindow`, `ShowDialog` and `ShowPopup` methods witch takes a ViewModel as an argument nad automatically creates and binds View to it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it so much difficult if I mix the two framework to use just this feature (in calliburn case)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easy by your self. look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practise-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm).

```
var result = this.uiDialogService.ShowDialog("Dialogwindow title goes here", dialogwindowVM);
```