# Double Click on tab header should open the tab content in new window.. Using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, window, mouseevent, tabcontrol

I am using MVVM. I have `TabItems` with headers `mytabItem`, `mytabItem2`. How to bind a function so that I can open a new `Window` on double click on Header of tab.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="79,0,0,0">
    <TabControl Name="myTabControl">
        <TabItem Name ="mytabItem" Header="Double cllick me">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello world!"/>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Name ="mytabItem1" Header="cllick me" MouseDoubleClick="">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello Water!"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: looks like you need a DialogueService. refer to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practise-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practise-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm)