# Prevent windows from opening

Tags: wpf, events, dialog, window, modal-dialog

Hi would like to ask a strange question. Its about testing a WPF application.

My current object under test is a WF application that spontaneously opens informational dialogs. Those dialogs are modal and can open every time. This is pretty disturbing for an automated test running on that application. Whenever my tester accesses the visual tree and try to access the GUI (like invoking buttons etc.) it can happen that such an dialog window opens, blocking the GUI by its modality and making the test fail.

One idea to solve this would be to prevent those dialogs from opening. I can not change the behaviour of the application under test directly but I can subscribe to all window events (like initialized, loaded, rendered, etc.). I would like to use one of those events to prevent the windows from opening and modally blocking the GUI.

I tried using the loaded event since it is the last event before the window is actually displayed however calling Close() on the corresponding window causes crashes. I also tried Hide()... this prevents the window from getting visible but the GUI is still blocked by the invisible dialog.

Does someone have an idea how I could effectively prevent a WPF window/dialog from opening or at least from modally blocking the GUI?

Comment: even if you could prevent it, you'd still have to provide a return value for dialogs having Ok/Cancel/Retry/... buttons. Anyway, the only real solution here is obvious: the source code should be modified in order to use something like an IModelDialogService eventually provided by some DI framework. Then while running tests you provide an implementation of that service that does nothing..

Comment: Hmmm... those informational, spontaneous dialogs do not have any other buttons then the standard close button and an "Ok" button. All dialogs that have something like "Retry" or "Cancel" etc. do not open spontaneously and can be expected and treated systematically (I already do so).

Isn't there a way for such basic dialogs too?

Answer (score 0):

if you use a [dialogservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practise-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm) for your dialogs you can simply mock this for your testing

Comment: Unfortunately there is only a very small chance that they will modify the application for my tests. So a method that does not require AUT modifications would be much better.