# Pause execution like a MessageBox or a Dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am creating an application that shows some alerts.
With MessageBox.Show its ok, but its ugly for this project. Its a Metro like app, so we created a Metro-like MessageBox.

Our custom MessageBox is a grid that changes its visibility when we need it.
The issue is that a real MessageBox, stops the execution util the user clicks its "ok".

So, how can I simulare this behavior?

Comment: show the message box on another thread

Comment: @ByteBlast why in another thread? explain me more please.

Comment: @RicardoPolo because `MessageBox.Show` blocks the current thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your custom messagebox a form. Then you can call `customMessageBoxFormInstance.ShowDialog()`.. which blocks exactly the same as a messagebox would.

This is what you would do:

- Create a form that resembles your custom `MessageBox`. Perhaps you can move your grid into it.
- Put a button on there which has it's `DialogResult` property set to `OK`.
- Use this wherever you want your alert to show up:

  ```
  if (customMessageBoxInstance.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
      // they clicked okay..
  }
  ```

It will block exactly as you expect a `MessageBox` to do..

Comment: I think I cant. I am using WPF with MVVM.

Comment: You can on a `Window`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your custom Show needs to block until the button is clicked, so this pseudocode should work, though better solutions may exist.  The MessageBox's UI would ideally run on a separate thread, but Show would be called from your main thread.

```
void Show()
{
   // set MessageBox visible
   ...

   // Wait until ok is pressed
   while(!complete){
       Thread.sleep(100);
   };

   complete = false;
   return;
}

// onClick handler for the OK button
void onClick()
{
   complete = true;
   // set message box invisible
}

private bool complete;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have done:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid x:Name="DialogOverlay">
   </Grid>
   <Grid x:Name="ViewContainer">
   <Grid>
</Grid>
```

When showing a modal dialog, put it in the DialogOverlay, make the overlay visible and disable  the ViewContainer grid. This prevents the user from clicking/tabbing into the regular UI.

When the dialog is closed you should hide the overaly and enable the ViewContainer.

Comment: +1.. while getting the job done, it also allows access to other parts of the application if design requires/allows for it, such as allowing to go to a different tab.

Comment: Yes, you can nest this construction anywhere you like so you block just that part of the UI that is being updated/waiting.

Answer (score 0):

i use a [DialogService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practise-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm) with MVVM - you can implement this for your CustomMessagebox.

```
var result = this.customMessageboxDialogService.ShowDialog("Dialogwindow title goes here", dialogwindowVM);

... do anything with the dialog result...
```