# Do I put eventhandling in the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm

Im trying to follow the MVVM pattern and have successfully implemented a loginpage for a user. But I need to let the user know if they enter a wrong username.

Do I implement a custom event in the `ViewModel`, and then add the listener in the View? Its a Windows Phone app so im just thinking of doing a `MessageBox` telling the user that the username does not exits.
Ill guess I have to subscribe to the event on `OnNavigatedTo` and desubscribe on `OnNavigatedFrom`?

Answer (score 0):

if your viewmodel has a logincommand and you just want to show a messagebox when its not succesfull, you can simply use a messageboxservice which you call from your viewmodel

viewmodel

```
var result = this.msgService.ShowDialog("bad login data");
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practice-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm) is a dialogservice, but you can adept it for your messageboxservice