# MvvmCross: How to recall the current view model again using ICommand?

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I tried to do a basic form validation to require some fields on the form must filled in.
I tried to do the Validation check on the ViewModel, I have a ValidateForm function and will return a ValidationMessage, however, when the SaveCommand get call and it won't call back the current View again, so the error message Alert View won't popup. How can I recall the current View Model again after SaveCommand finished?

```
    private string _ValidationMessage;

    public string ValidationMessage
    {
        get { return _ValidationMessage; }
        set
        {
            _ValidationMessage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => ValidationMessage);
        }
    }

    private string ValideForm()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ZipCode))
            return "Fields with * are required.";

        return null;
    }

    private MvxCommand _saveCommand;

    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _saveCommand = _saveCommand ?? new MvxCommand(SaveCommandHandler);
            return _saveCommand;
        }
    }

    private void SaveCommandHandler()
    {
        var validationMessage = ValideForm();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationMessage))
        {
            ValidationMessage = validationMessage;
            return;
        }

        ShowViewModel<NextScreenViewModel>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the same question as [MvvmCross Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609018/mvvmcross-dialog). The poster there suggests several ways to do this, and my answer covers one more 'architectural' way to do it too.

If you'd prefer a simpler way, then you can also just use a string property - eg `ErrorMessage`. The view can listen for changes in that string. When they happen,
 then the view can display an error dialog. This is a bit like the approach taken for Progress Dialogs in this video and code - N=34 - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/n34-showing-progress-isbusy-display-n1.html