# MvvmCross navigation on screen

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

[image: screen]

Our designer created a layout something like the screen above. The main idea was to create an application with only one screen, just the red part of the screen is changing (i.e. 2 textbox instead of 1 textbox) when you tap on a button. This application will be a multiplatform application and I'm using MvvmCross to create it. My question is that how can i achieve this behavior in Mvvm? My first thought was sg. like the code below, but I'm not satisfied with this solution. Do you have any better solution to this problem? Should i somehow overwrite default navigation on ShowViewModel()?

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
     private MvxViewModel _currentViewModel;
     public MvxViewModel CurrentViewModel
     {
         get { return _currentViewModel; }
         set { _currentViewModel = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentViewModel); }
     }

     public MainViewModel()
     {
         CurrentViewModel = new DefaultViewModel();
     }

     public void OnButtonClick()
     {
         CurrentViewModel = new SecondViewModel();
     }
 }

 public partial class MainViewModel : MvxViewController
 {

      public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        FirstViewModel.WeakSubscribe(ViewModelPropertyChanged);
    }

      private void ViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.PropertyName == "CurrentViewModel")
        {
            if (Model.CurrentViewModel != null)
            {
                if (Model.CurrentViewModel is SecondViewModel) 
                {
                                            //remove bindings
                    //change View
                                            //bind new viewmodel
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternatives for this kind of 'non-page navigation' are similar to those in [MvvmCross Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609018/mvvmcross-dialog):

You can:

- Customize the `MvxPresenter` to allow ShowViewModel to be used
- Put a special interface in the Core project and use Inversion of Control to inject the implementation from the UI project to the Core project
- Use the MvxMessenger plugin and share messages between the Core and UI project which trigger this type of navigation.
- Use a property with a special interface (like `IInteractionRequest`) on the ViewModel - that property will fire an event when the UI needs to change.

Personally, for your situation, I quite like the first of these options - intercepting `ShowViewModel` using a presenter.

One other alternative which I might consider is to use some kind of 'Adapter-driven' control which could very easily update it's child contents based on the `CurrentViewModel` property. On Android, this would be as easy as using an `MvxLinearLayout` with an adapter. On iOS, however, I think you'd have to write something new to do this - just because iOS doesn't really have a LinearLayout/StackPanel control.