# create a dialog in android with Mvvmcross based on layout

Tags: android, mvvmcross

Sorry if this looks so easy, but I looked to the N+1 video about dialogs and it's showing creating a dialog in code and not by using the layout.

Here's what I did:

ChangePasswordView.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/oldpassword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/YourOldPassword"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            local:MvxBind="Text OldPassword" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/newpassword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="@string/YourNewPassword"
            local:MvxBind="Text NewPassword" />
        <Button
            android:text="@string/ChangePassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            local:MvxBind="Click ChangePasswordCommand"
            android:paddingRight="42dp"
            android:paddingLeft="42dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

ChangePasswordView.cs:

```
[Activity]
    public class ChangePasswordView : MvxDialogActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            DroidResources.Initialise(typeof(Resource.Layout));
            this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ChangePassword);
        }
        }
```

Calling the display of the dialog from a view model:

```
void ChangePassword()
{
  this.ShowViewModel<ChangePasswordViewModel>();
}
```

I also have Setup.cs:

```
public class Setup : MvxAndroidDialogSetup
{
 ...
}
```

Running results in an error complaining about:

```
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some confusion here about what 'Dialog' is

#### Dialog 1 - https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog and https://github.com/kevinmcmahon/MonoDroid.Dialog

A Dialog in the sense of http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n23-dialogs-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html is a MonoTouch.Dialog or MonoDroid.Dialog based 'data form'.

These are defined in code - because that's what MonoTouch.Dialog and MonoDroid.Dialog are about. For Droid, you can override individual Elements of the display - each Element is loaded from a resource - but you can't load the whole 'Activity' as a resource.

#### Dialog 2 - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

If you are not looking for MonoTouch.Dialog style pages, but are instead looking for Android native popup *dialog*s, then there isn't much about these in MvvmCross. There is a sample of a fragment resource-based dialog in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Fragments/FragmentSample.UI.Droid/Views/HomeView.cs and some interesting recent discussion about how to display them in [MvvmCross Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609018/mvvmcross-dialog)

Comment: Thank you Stuart. I somehow expected that an AlertDialog like would be created based on the layout, similar to how an activity is created. But I guess there might be different implications which I cannot see.