# MvvmCross bind to InteractionRequest

Tags: binding, modal-dialog, mvvmcross

I am attempting to implement a modal confirmation popup using mvvmcross in iOS, following the Stuart's outline in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609018/mvvmcross-dialog/18624500#18624500).  I get the following exception when attempting to bind the InteractionRequest to the Event handler:

```
Problem seen during binding execution for to ConfirmationInteraction - problem
TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

The inner exception is:

```
ArgumentNullException: missing source event info in MvxWeakEventSubscription
Parameter name: sourceEventInfo
at Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`2[System.Object,System.EventArgs]..ctor (System.Object source, System.Reflection.EventInfo sourceEventInfo, System.EventHandler`1 targetEventHandler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxGeneralEventSubscription..ctor (System.Object source, System.Reflection.EventInfo eventInfo, System.EventHandler`1 eventHandler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakSubscriptionExtensionMethods.WeakSubscribe (System.Reflection.EventInfo eventInfo, System.Object source, System.EventHandler`1 eventHandler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Most of the plumbing is identical to the referenced stack overflow question above, but I will post it here for completeness:

```
public class InteractionRequestedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Action Callback 
    { 
        get; 
        private set; 
    }

    public object Context 
    { 
        get; 
        private set; 
    }

    public InteractionRequestedEventArgs(object context, Action callback)
    {
        Context = context;
        Callback = callback;
    }
}
```

The InteractionRequest:

```
public class InteractionRequest<T> : IInteractionRequest
{
    public event EventHandler<InteractionRequestedEventArgs> Raised;

    public void Raise(T context, Action<T> callback)
    {
        var handler = this.Raised;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(
                this, 
                new InteractionRequestedEventArgs(
                context, 
                () => callback(context)));
        }
    }
}
```

The confirmation class:

```
public class Confirmation
{
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public bool Confirmed { get; set; }
    public Confirmation(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

In the view model we set up the request as so:

```
private InteractionRequest<Confirmation> _confirmCancelInteractionRequest = new InteractionRequest<Confirmation>();
    public IInteractionRequest ConfirmCancelInteractionRequest
    {
        get
        {
            return _confirmCancelInteractionRequest;
        }
    }
```

in the view we set up the event subscription:

```
    private MvxGeneralEventSubscription _confirmationSubscription;
    private IInteractionRequest _confirmationInteraction;
    public IInteractionRequest ConfirmationInteraction
    {
        get { 
            return _confirmationInteraction; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (_confirmationInteraction == value)
                return;
            if (_confirmationSubscription != null)
                _confirmationSubscription.Dispose();
            _confirmationInteraction = value;
            if (_confirmationInteraction != null)
                _confirmationSubscription = _confirmationInteraction
                    .GetType ()
                    .GetEvent ("Raise")
                    .WeakSubscribe(_confirmationInteraction, DoConfirmation);

        }
    }
```

The event handler in the view looks like this:

```
private void DoConfirmation(object s, EventArgs args)
    {
        var iArgs = (InteractionRequestedEventArgs)args;
        var confirmation = (Confirmation)iArgs.Context;

        var alert = new UIAlertView(); 
        alert.Title = "Bazinga"; 
        alert.Message = confirmation.Message; 

        alert.AddButton("Yes"); 
        alert.AddButton("No"); 

        alert.Clicked += (sender, e) => { 
            var alertView = sender as UIAlertView; 
                            // do something with the event
            iArgs.Callback();
        }; 
    }
```

Finally the binding, which is inside the constructor for the view.  The view is a MT Dialog Element, hence the DelayBind():

```
this.DelayBind(() =>
        {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<CustomerElement, CustomerViewModel>();
            ...
            set.Bind().For(my => my.ConfirmationInteraction).To(customer => customer.ConfirmCancelInteractionRequest);
            set.Apply();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null reference exception with the stack

```
at Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`2[System.Object,System.EventArgs]..ctor (System.Object source, System.Reflection.EventInfo sourceEventInfo, System.EventHandler`1 targetEventHandler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxGeneralEventSubscription..ctor (System.Object source, System.Reflection.EventInfo eventInfo, System.EventHandler`1 eventHandler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakSubscriptionExtensionMethods.WeakSubscribe (System.Reflection.EventInfo eventInfo, System.Object source, System.EventHandler`1 eventHandler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

can only occur if `_confirmationInteraction.GetType ().GetEvent ("Raise")` returns `null`

So... I think the problem might be that your event is called `Raised`

---

If it helps:

- the 3.0.13 release of MvvmCross included some initial helpers for interactions - e.g. see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxInteraction.cs - I do hope and expect that we'll build upon this in coming releases
- for simple "message box" interactions @BrianChance has provided this fab plugin - https://github.com/brianchance/MvvmCross-UserInteraction

Comment: I've also gone back and corrected the original answer too - hopefully that will help others (Thanks!)

Comment: Thanks Stuart.  What I'm now getting a type mismatch when binding.

Comment: `code` Object type System.EventHandler cannot be converted to target type: System.EventHandler`1[[QuickAssessment.Core.Interaction.InteractionRequestedEventArgs, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
   at System.Reflection.Binder.ConvertValue (System.Object value, System.Type type, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, Boolean exactMatch) [0x00027] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Binder.cs:93

Comment: Sorry—the enter key seems to want to commit the comments before I’m finished.  It looks like a type mismatch, although InterationRequestedEventArgs does inherit from System.EventArgs.  Anyway,  I’ll take a look at some of the other solutions mentioned as they will likely fit the bill for the time being. Thanks again.

Comment: The message is telling you what is wrong - use the typed eventargs argument in `DoConfirmation(object s, EventArgs args)`