# How to show a MvxDialogFragment from ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

In this example https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/DialogExamples/DialogExamples.Droid

the MvxDialogFragment is launched from the Activity.

How can I do to show My MvxDialogFragment directly from ViemModel?

I have two ViewModels:  ListViewModel  And DetailViewModel

In ListViewModel:

```
public DetailViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _SelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedItem = value;
            ShowViewModel<DetailViewModel>(new { id = value.Model.Id }); //Show my activity in Dialog mode
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609018/mvvmcross-dialog

Comment: Thank you Stuart but it is not what I need, I don't need juste an confirmation, I need to retrieve  somme Data that's why I need to do that via fragment. I found MvxDialogFragment class to do that but I can't show it directly from my viewModel, and there is no class for DialogActivity in your framework.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by a class for `DialogActivity`. Perhaps you could include more detail (code, diagrams, explanation) in your question to explain what you are looking to do.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should look into [this](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Fragments).
It contains an example of an [MvxDialogFragment](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Fragments/FragmentSample.UI.Droid/Views/Frags/Dialog) with its [viewmodel](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Fragments/FragmentSample.Core/ViewModels/Dialog)

Comment: The OP is asking how to display that fragment via ViewModel and NOT from the UI layer