# MvvmCross watch property from View

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I want my android View to trigger a method to create a Toast message whenever a certain property changes in the ViewModel.  All the examples I'm finding are binding within the XML.  This seems so much simpler yet I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by creating a weak subscription to the viewmodel inside the view and showing the toast when the property changes as follows:-

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        IMvxNotifyPropertyChanged viewModel = ViewModel as IMvxNotifyPropertyChanged;
        viewModel.WeakSubscribe(PropertyChanged);
        return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);            
    }

    private void PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "the property")
        {
            //Display toast
        }
    }
```

I would be tempted however to instead allow your viewmodel to control this behaviour (are you going to write the above code for every implementation?)

Simply add the [UserInteraction](https://github.com/brianchance/MvvmCross-UserInteraction) plugin via nuget and do the following:

```
private readonly IUserInteraction _userInteraction;

public FirstViewModel(IUserInteraction userInteraction)
{
    _userInteraction = userInteraction;
}

private string _hello = "Hello MvvmCross";
public string Hello
{ 
    get { return _hello; }
    set
    {
        _hello = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Hello);
        _userInteraction.Alert("Property Changed!");
    }
}
```

This doesn't display a toast, it displays a message box, but hopefully it will give you enough to go off.

Finally you could use a messenger plugin to send a "Show toast" message.

Comment: In addition to these suggestions, you can also use the interation request pattern - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609018/mvvmcross-dialog/18624500#18624500