# RaisePropertyChanaged in Mvvmcross from one class to another class

Tags: android, xamarin, event-handling, mvvmcross

```
public class CartItemViewModel : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public double SubTotal
    {
        get { return UnitPrice * Quantity; }
        set
        {
            //RaisePropertyChanged("TotalValue")
        }
    }
 }

 public class CartViewModel : MvxViewModel
 {
     public double TotalValue 
     {
        get
        {
            foreach (var item in cartlist) 
            {
                totalvalue += item.UnitPrice;
            }
            return totalvalue;
        }
        set
        {
            TotalValue = value;
        }
    }
    private double totalvalue;
   }
```

I want to modify `TotalValue` property when `SubTotal` property is changed. Both are in different classes. How to make it possible?
It is not working when I pop up `Raispropertychanged("TotalValue")` in `SubTotal`.
Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the `PropertyChanged` event for all the instances of `CartItemViewModel` inside the `CartViewModel`. 
You receive `PropertyChangedEventArgs` which has a member called `PropertyName`. When its value is "SubTotal" then you can call `Raispropertychanged(TotalValue)`. 
The code is completely added to `CartViewModel`.

Comment: Can You give me an example ? @wosi

Comment: Take a look at the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849112/mvvmcross-watch-property-from-view