# MessageBox is not recommended in MVVM applications?

Tags: c#, mvvm, dialog

When I asked about how to implement a dialog in MVVM someone advised me to read this thread:

[MVVM, DialogService and Dialog Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779674/mvvm-dialogservice-and-dialog-result)

In the view model, the dialog is called in this way:

```
var dialog = new DialogViewmodel();
var result = _dialogservice.ShowDialog("My Dialog", dialog);

if(result.HasValue && result.Value)
{
    //accept true
}
else
{
    //Cancel or false
}
```

But is this different than using a messageBox in this way?

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Hello");

if(result == DialgoResult-OK)
{
    //accept true
}
else
{
    //Cancel or false
}
```

In this second case, I use MessageBox instead of the custom dialog, so I don't see any difference.

Anyway, in many cases I have read that to use a MessageBox in MVVM application it is a bad idea because it breaks the MVVM pattern. But really if this is true, I don't see how the first solution doesn't break the MVVM pattern and the second one breaks it.

Comment: Every messagebox is a U/X design error because it interrupts the user.

Comment: But in MVVM and Software Architecture context, try to look at it in terms of dependencies and testability. A VM that calls MessagBox directly is much harder to test.

Comment: Why not just create an `IAlertService` to handle `MessageBox`s in exactly the same way you did for dialogs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How have you successfully implemented MessageBox.Show() functionality in MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098023/how-have-you-successfully-implemented-messagebox-show-functionality-in-mvvm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea of the MVVM pattern is the separation of concerns. The View Model should not know how to handle or present a dialog. Why? Here are some reasons:

- Testing your View Model: No dialogs are desired (Imagine you need to click dialogs all the time)
- Creating a console application of a GUI application (The dialogs should be shown in console not as popup boxes)
- It is required to change the design of your dialogs (Imagine you need to change all MessageBox calls)
- ...

**Solution:**
Using dependency injection by implementing a well defined interface for dialogs. You can find a very good and basic example in in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877671/showing-a-message-box-from-the-viewmodel-is-a-violation-of-mvvm-how-to-avoid).

**Result:**
Calling `_dialogservice.ShowDialog` is maybe only a wrapper of `MessageBox.Show` but could also be a some dialog in a console in a console application or debug log during testing. So the code is well separated of any presentation.

Comment: OP just needs the equivalent to `IAlertService` as per his dialog service.  Whether it is provided by DI is neither here nor there

Comment: why not a custom overlay control instead in the main window?

Comment: Because you cant call it from a view model directly.