# How can I test the Text on MessageBox?(message text : "Data succussfully saved")

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, telerik, vs-unit-testing-framework

Actually, I want to test the MessageBox, means text displayed on messagebox is correct or not.How can I test the text on messagebox in Unit Testing?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/4560542/how-to-suppress-a-message-box-while-unit-testing

Answer (score 0):

dont take a messagebox - the a "service". eg: [Good or bad practice for Dialogs in wpf with MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practice-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm)

here you can test the dialog viewmodel

Comment: Thank you all, for your response. Here i want to test the Text message on Message Box ("Data successfully saved."), Here I am using Telerik Testing Framework. In this frame work, first of all create Object for that class and then accessing the value. I am trying to create an object for Message Box class but, here object was not created because no Default constructors is not available for that class. I am creating Wrapper class for Message Box class and create an object for Wrapper class in unit test class now its working, But i want is there any different approaches are available or not?

Answer (score 0):

Here i Used Content Dialog Box.

Button_Click Code

```
ContentDialog msg = new ContentDialog();
        msg.Content = "Data Saved Successfully";
        msg.ContentTemplate = Application.Current.Resources["ContentDialogContentTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
        msg.PrimaryButtonText = CommonDisplayMessages.DisplayMessage_Yes;
```

await msg.ShowAsync();