# Show View as a dialog box

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I used devexpress hybrid wpf scaffolding wizard to generate a full MVVM

application with views for collections and single object views.

Now I'm struggling to figure out how to make some of the single object views popup when double clicked from the collection view, as a metroUI dialog and not like a frame with a back button.

Comment: you want open a dialog from your viewmodel?

Comment: I want the view to appear as a dialog.

Comment: thats what i use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practice-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm looking for devexpress specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the [IDialogSerivice](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17467) and it's [WinUIDialogService](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17468) implementation to accomplish this task. 
Since you are using [scaffolding](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17425), you should go into your collection view 
(`YouEntityCollectionView.xaml`) and go into `Behaviors` section:

```
<dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <dxwui:WinUIMessageBoxService/>
    <dxmvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding OnLoadedCommand}" />
    <WindowedDocumentUIService YieldToParent="True"/>
</dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Then add your service into this section:

```
<dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <dxwui:WinUIMessageBoxService/>
    <dxmvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding OnLoadedCommand}" />
    <dxwui:WinUIDialogService />
</dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

After that you should replace the `IDocumentManagerService` with `IDialogService` within the `CollectionViewModel` code. It may look as follows:

```
// Edit:
//DocumentManagerService.ShowExistingEntityDocument<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>(this, primaryKey);
this.GetService<IDialogService>().ShowDialog(MessageButton.OKCancel, null, typeof(TEntity).Name + "View", primaryKey, this);

// New:
//DocumentManagerService.ShowNewEntityDocument(this, newEntityInitializer);
this.GetService<IDialogService>().ShowDialog(MessageButton.OKCancel, null, typeof(TEntity).Name + "View", newEntityInitializer, this);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it and let you know.