# Modal Dialog in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, showmodaldialog

Here is my problem: I am migrating an application from Windows Forms to WPF, but I am totally new in WPF technology.

I have been lucky creating a ribbon also have been able to add some elements to it, but right now I am struggling to create a modal dialog.

How can I achieve this? I have already created all the design of the dialog, but I cannot get it open as a modal window.

Besides, since this application has to be developed under MVVM pattern, where could I place that code? According to what I've read, that code has to be place in the view class, am I right?.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do make modal dialog in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499294/how-do-make-modal-dialog-in-wpf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You show a WPF Window modally using [Window.ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx).  Also this [WPF Window Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx) will help.

> Besides, since this application has to be developed under MVVM
> pattern, where could I place that code?

Look under the Related questions to your right, there are many answers to this question in there.  For example:

[Open dialog in WPF MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805778/open-dialog-in-wpf-mvvm)

Comment: using Window.ShowDialog. is not a MMV conform solution. The ViewModel should not access the View.

Comment: @kux The ViewModel doesn't have to if you use an event in code-behind ;) But I agree, it should be a Command in the ViewModel while also not knowing about the View.