# Displaying read only properties in PropertyGrid control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpftoolkit

I am using the WPF Extended Toolkit to display the properties of a **Team** object. Now one of these properties is a collection **Persons**. No problem I get a nice drop down, which when I click on shows me the names and ages of each of these people.

[image]

Now the problem is that I don't actually want to expose my Collection as public. However as soon as I make its setter private the property is disabled preventing the user from seeing the Person collection and the person details:

[image]

How should I display my Person Collection when its setter is private? Can I do this with a XAML template? If so how? I'm using MVVM so I don't want to put anything in the code behind.

**Update**

OK so the solution by @tencntraze got me most of the way there - thanks.
However it doesn't work for Collections of objects which is what I've got in my case. In addition it can also be simplified to use the [CollectionControlDialog](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/CollectionControlDialog) instead of the custom ReadOnlyCollectionViewer that's been implemented below.

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="DevExpressTreeList.ReadOnlyCollectionEditor"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Name="MyUserControl"
             >
    <DockPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_OnClick" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <Label Content="˅" Padding="2,0,2,0" />
        </Button>
        <Label Name="CollectionLabel" Content="(Collection)" Padding="2,2,2,0" />
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code-Behind

```
public partial class ReadOnlyCollectionEditor : UserControl, ITypeEditor
{
    public ReadOnlyCollectionEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Use typeof(object) to allow for any Collection<T>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value", typeof(object), typeof(ReadOnlyCollectionEditor), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

    public object Value
    {
        // We are now using object so no need to cast
        get { return GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public FrameworkElement ResolveEditor(Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyItem propertyItem)
    {
        var binding = new Binding("Value")
        {
            Source = propertyItem,
            Mode = propertyItem.IsReadOnly ? BindingMode.OneWay : BindingMode.TwoWay
        };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ValueProperty, binding);
        return this;
    }

    private void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var collectionControlDialog = new CollectionControlDialog
        {
            ItemsSource = (IList)this.Value
        };
        collectionControlDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a read-only collection?

Comment: @Alberto yes I have although it makes no difference.

Comment: why don't you want your property to be public?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish.  Do you want to see the list but not be able to edit it, or maybe not change the selection.  Can you elaborate a bit please.

Comment: Fair question. I'm working with an interface I can't really change. It does makes sense though for that interface have only read-only properties. I just need to be able to show the user the contents of the collection. Telling them simply that "it is a collection" isn't very helpful.

Comment: Did you check here under the section Customer ItemsSource?
https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Home

Comment: @Xcalibur37 Yes I tried adding the ItemsSource attribute but that didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that your best bet here is to implement your own editor, as per the [Xceed Documentation](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/PropertyGrid#custom-editors).  You are then able to provide whatever UI you would like to display to the user without needing to commit the values back to the underlying object.  Note that this approach works for both private setters as well as properties without any setter.

**ReadOnlyCollectionEditor**

*XAML*

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.ReadOnlyCollectionEditor"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Name="uc">
    <Button Click="Button_OnClick" Height="20" />
</UserControl>
```

*Code-Behind*

```
public partial class ReadOnlyCollectionEditor : UserControl, ITypeEditor
{
    public ReadOnlyCollectionEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value", typeof (IList<string>), typeof (ReadOnlyCollectionEditor), new PropertyMetadata(default(IList<string>)));

    public IList<string> Value
    {
        get { return (IList<string>)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public FrameworkElement ResolveEditor(Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyItem propertyItem)
    {
        var binding = new Binding("Value")
        {
            Source = propertyItem,
            Mode = propertyItem.IsReadOnly ? BindingMode.OneWay : BindingMode.TwoWay
        };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ValueProperty, binding);
        return this;
    }

    private void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadOnlyCollectionViewer viewer = new ReadOnlyCollectionViewer {DataContext = this};
        viewer.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**ReadOnlyCollectionViewer**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.ReadOnlyCollectionViewer"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ReadOnlyCollectionViewer" Height="300" Width="300">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" />
</Window>
```

**Sample Properties Class**

```
public class MyDataObjects
{
    public MyDataObjects()
    {
        this.CollectionProperty = new Collection<string> {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};            
        this.StringProperty = "Hi!";
    }

    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    [Editor(typeof(ReadOnlyCollectionEditor), typeof(ReadOnlyCollectionEditor))]
    public ICollection<string> CollectionProperty { get; private set; } 
}
```

**Assigning to the property grid**

```
this.propertyGrid.SelectedObject = new MyDataObjects();
```

**Results**

[image: Main Window]

[image]

EDIT

I realize that you want to use MVVM, which I strongly encourage when using WPF, but for purposes of this sample I believe that keeping it simple helps illustrate the point, otherwise it brings up other questions like [showing a modal dialog from MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805778/open-dialog-in-wpf-mvvm), so I'm just showing the dialog with a button click.

Comment: This is a good answer, however as you mentioned, not MVVM friendly. I've just asked something that would go in the same direction, I'd like to pass control of that button click to the ViewModel of the View that contains the PropertyGrid... link here if you know the answer plz help :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125563/xceed-wpftoolkit-propertygrid-custom-typeeditor-bindable-command

Answer (score 1):

```
public Collection<Person> People
{
    get { return _people; }
    set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
}
```

Perhaps not the nicest solution but it will work with the PropertyGrid while preventing users setting a new collection.

Comment: Throwing an exception is not an option in this case