# what needs to be done handle dialog windows in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

what all necessary steps to be done to handle dialog windows in MVVM.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454868/handling-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Handling Dialogs in WPF with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454868/handling-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the ViewModel sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how a dialog can be shown.