# How can i also pass parameter to new open window using Mvvm Light Toolkit

Tags: wpf, mvvm

from this thread [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386349/how-to-open-a-new-window-using-mvvm-light-toolkit)

i can open new window by using message [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3388241/987024), but i also want to pass parameter to new open windows.
Any idea for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom class that inherits NotificationMessage and set what you want in it and pass it and then on view side cast it back to your custom class. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NotificationMessage<T>`, there is no need to inherit from `NotificationMessage`.

e.g. (I'm using the Telerik Docking forms container in my project, so you can ignore the RadPane stuff - hopefully you get the idea)

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;

public MainWindow()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<MyEntities.Company>>(this, (c) => NotificationMessageReceived(c.Notification, c.Content));
}

private void NotificationMessageReceived (string msg, MyEntities.Company c)
{
   if (msg == "ShowCompany") 
   {
      var CompanyPane = new RadDocumentPane();

      CompanyPane.Header = c.Name; // I use the  Name property of my company entity here

      CompanyPane.Content = new Views.CompanySummaryView(); 
      this.radPaneGroup.AddItem(CompanyPane, DockPosition.Center);
   }
}
```

In the View Model where I want to open my new Window I have this Method which I call from a Command. This just sends the message with the Company entity embedded.

```
public void EditCompany()
{
    Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage<MyEntities.Company>>(new NotificationMessage<MyEntities.Company>(Companies.FirstOrDefault(), "ShowCompany"));
}
```