# How to Create WPF Browser Application in MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I want to Create WPF Browser Application in MVVM pattern. 
I have VS2012 and SQL Server.
I already install MvvmLight.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) On this website, it is customary for question authors to put a bit more effort into their questions and at least show their attempts at trying to fulfil their requirements, so that other users don't think that they want to have all of their work done for them. Are you stuck on a particular part of your implementation?

Comment: Or, to answer your question with the same amount of effort that you put into it, use a [`WebBrowser` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Sheridan - He wants a [XBAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060(v=vs.110).aspx), and i don't see why it is any different than a normal WPF application using MVVM pattern.

Comment: Do they want to create a XAML Browser Application, or just a normal web browser application using WPF? Of course, we don't really know because of the lack of information in their question.

Comment: @Sheridan I just want to create XAML Browser Application with MVVM Pattern

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a new window using MVVM Light Toolkit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386349/how-to-open-a-new-window-using-mvvm-light-toolkit)

Comment: Your question has already been put on hold by the community because of its brevity. You can edit your question to provide (far) more details of the *specific* problems that you faced when trying to implement your requirements and then it may be re-opened and answered. Please read the page that I provided a link for in my first comment, so that you know how to ask a good quality question here... one that won't be put on hold.