# MVVM ViewModel and static methods

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, static

I try to rewrite my Application using the MVVM pattern.

I have a window to show related documents for different objects with static methods like this:

```
    public partial class ShowRelatedDocuments : Window
    {

    private ShowRelatedDocuments()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static void ShowRelatedDocument(A objA)
    {
        ShowRelatedDocuments srd = new ShowRelatedDocuments();
        srd.HandleA(objA);
        srd.ShowDialog();
    }

    public static void ShowRelatedDocument(B objB)
    {
        ShowRelatedDocuments srd = new ShowRelatedDocuments();
        srd.HandleB(objB);
        srd.ShowDialog();
    }}
```

Is there a way to keep these methods static like this?

```
ShowRelatedDocumentsVM.ShowRelatedDocument(A objA);
ShowRelatedDocumentsVM.ShowRelatedDocument(B objB);
```

I didn't find anything about ViewModels and static methods. Can a VM create a instance of itself and show his View (here a window)?

Or is the better way to pass the objects as parameter to the constructor of the VM like this?

```
public ShowRelatedDocumentsVM(A objA)
{
  HandleA(obj A)
  ShowRelatedDocuments srd = new ShowRelatedDocuments();
  srd.DataContext = this;
  srd.ShowDialog();
}

public ShowRelatedDocumentsVM(B objB)
{
  HandleB(objB);
  ShowRelatedDocuments srd = new ShowRelatedDocuments();
  srd.DataContext = this;
  srd.ShowDialog();
}
```

Or are both ways wrong, cause i breach the MVVM pattern due creating the view in the viewmodel?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to display dialogs is one of the areas of MVVM that is not immediately clear, and there are a number of ways the behaviour can be achieved.

I would suggest using either a mediator (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454868/handling-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm)) or by injecting a dependency on the view model that controls dialogs:

```
interface IDialogService
{
    void ShowRelatedDocumentsA(A a);
}
```

...

```
class MyViewModel
{
    private IDialogService _dialogService

    public MyViewModel(IDialogService dialogService) { _dialogService = dialogService; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _dialogService.ShowDialog(...);
    }
}
```

Either of these can will permit you to control the creation of the view outside of the view model, and will remove any explicit references from VM -> V.

Comment: The IDialogService or IMessageBoxService is the most common way I've seen this problem solved. It's also testable. +1