# Save and Close in Current Window in WPF-MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have two buttons Save, Save & Close in my window. If user clicks on Save, I am able to successfully save the details. I am unable to figure out on how to close window, when user clicks on Save & Close. Here is my code for Save

```
<telerik:RadButton x:Name="button_Save" Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveProductCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ProductName, Path=Text}" />
```

Here is my Relay Command.

```
public ICommand SaveProductCommand
{
  get 
  {
    return new RelayCommand<string>(SaveProductExecute);
  } 
 }
```

My First Question:

Can we pass one more parameter True or false for Save and Save&Close ? So that we can use only one Relay Command for both ?

Second Question:

How to close current Window after Saving ?

Answer (score 2):

Good Question..the key here is to use `Action`.Take a look at my sample

We will try to keep coding to minimal..

> Can we pass one more parameter True or false for Save and Save&Close ? So that we can use only one Relay Command for both ?

Since you havent mentioned how you are passing true or false I have included a Listbox which has two string items `True` and `False`.

If `true` is selected only one part of command will execute and if `false` is selected we will perform both the methods in the command.

1. Create a view with **Button** and **Listbox**

   ```
     <ListBox x:Name="items">
       <System:String>True</System:String>
       <System:String>False</System:String>
     </ListBox>

   <Button Content="MyButton" Command="{Binding Path=MyCustomCommand}" 
   CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=items}"/>
   ```
2. Create ViewModel i.e **MyViewModel.cs**

   ```
   public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {

      public Action CloseAction { get; set; }
      public ICommand MyCustomCommand { get; set; }


      public MyViewModel()
      {
         MyCustomCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(MyFunction));
      }


      private void MyFunction(object MyCommandParameter)
      {
       if (Convert.ToString(MyCommandParameter) == "True")
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Save Executed");
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Save Execcuted");
           CloseAction();
       }
   }
   ```
3. In View Codebehind

   ```
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
     {
        public MainWindow()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           MyViewModel mv = new MyViewModel();
           this.DataContext = mv;

           if (mv.CloseAction == null)
               mv.CloseAction = new Action(() => this.Close());
         }
     }
   ```

Comment: What is that listbox ? I dont have that, I have to determine true or false based on button click. How can I do that ?

Comment: How will you determine if you want to execute both part of methods or only one method.Listbox is  just an example

Comment: Mine in UserControl not window. So, I am unable to get hold of this.Close()

Comment: CloseAction(); this is throwing null reference exception. In fact I figured out how to close usercontrol window

Comment: There is no such concept as "closing a control". And I don't think that such concept, if existed, could be of any use. You can: 1) hide the user control if it is no longer needed, maybe temporarily; 2) permanently remove the control from the logical tree.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317064/disconnecting-an-element-from-any-unspecified-parent-container-in-wpf

Comment: public partial class MainWindow : Window this one looks as public partial class AddProduct : UserControl in .cs file. So, Am unable to get Close(). How can I get that ?

Answer (score 0):

to ans your 2 questions --

yes you can multi bind ... doing something like this ..

```
<Button.CommandParameter>
    <MultiBinding>
         <Binding Path="path" ElementName="elementName"/>
         <Binding Path="path2" ElementName="elementName2"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.CommandParameter>
```

and there are many ways to close the window please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945821/implementing-close-window-command-with-mvvm) and [here](http://jkshay.com/closing-a-wpf-window-using-mvvm-and-minimal-code-behind/)

Answer (score 0):

Consider leveraging messaging with parameters to pass around data between your objects.

You can use an [EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) or [MessageBus](https://bizmonger.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/decoupled-event-management/).

The idea is to have your user controls subscribe to events that they would like to respond to.

NOTE:

I do this with viewmodels.
However, I think it is a code-smell when adding this code to user-controls that are meant to have general use regardless of the application employing them.

I use the ***Publish Subscribe pattern*** for complicated class-dependencies:

**ViewModel:**

```
    public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            CloseComand = new DelegateCommand((obj) =>
                {
                    MessageBus.Instance.Publish(Messages.REQUEST_DEPLOYMENT_SETTINGS_CLOSED, null);
                });
        }
}
```

**Window:**

```
public partial class SomeWindow : Window
{
    Subscription _subscription = new Subscription();

    public SomeWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _subscription.Subscribe(Messages.REQUEST_DEPLOYMENT_SETTINGS_CLOSED, obj =>
            {
                this.Close();
            });
    }
}
```

You can leverage [Bizmonger.Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) to get the MessageBus.

**MessageBus**

```
public class MessageBus
{
    #region Singleton
    static MessageBus _messageBus = null;
    private MessageBus() { }

    public static MessageBus Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_messageBus == null)
            {
                _messageBus = new MessageBus();
            }

            return _messageBus;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Members
    List<Observer> _observers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _oneTimeObservers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _waitingSubscribers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _waitingUnsubscribers = new List<Observer>();

    int _publishingCount = 0;
    #endregion

    public void Subscribe(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        Subscribe(message, response, _observers);
    }

    public void SubscribeFirstPublication(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        Subscribe(message, response, _oneTimeObservers);
    }

    public int Unsubscribe(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Respond == response).ToList());
        observers.AddRange(_waitingSubscribers.Where(o => o.Respond == response));
        observers.AddRange(_oneTimeObservers.Where(o => o.Respond == response));

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.ForEach(o => _observers.Remove(o));
        }

        else
        {
            _waitingUnsubscribers.AddRange(observers);
        }

        return observers.Count;
    }

    public int Unsubscribe(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription).ToList());
        observers.AddRange(_waitingSubscribers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));
        observers.AddRange(_oneTimeObservers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.ForEach(o => _observers.Remove(o));
        }

        else
        {
            _waitingUnsubscribers.AddRange(observers);
        }

        return observers.Count;
    }

    public void Publish(string message, object payload)
    {
        _publishingCount++;

        Publish(_observers, message, payload);
        Publish(_oneTimeObservers, message, payload);
        Publish(_waitingSubscribers, message, payload);

        _oneTimeObservers.RemoveAll(o => o.Subscription == message);
        _waitingUnsubscribers.Clear();

        _publishingCount--;
    }

    private void Publish(List<Observer> observers, string message, object payload)
    {
        Debug.Assert(_publishingCount >= 0);

        var subscribers = observers.Where(o => o.Subscription.ToLower() == message.ToLower());

        foreach (var subscriber in subscribers)
        {
            subscriber.Respond(payload);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Observer> GetObservers(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));
        return observers;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _observers.Clear();
        _oneTimeObservers.Clear();
    }

    #region Helpers
    private void Subscribe(string message, Action<object> response, List<Observer> observers)
    {
        Debug.Assert(_publishingCount >= 0);

        var observer = new Observer() { Subscription = message, Respond = response };

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.Add(observer);
        }
        else
        {
            _waitingSubscribers.Add(observer);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

**Subscription**

```
public class Subscription
{
    #region Members
    List<Observer> _observerList = new List<Observer>();
    #endregion

    public void Unsubscribe(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = _observerList.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription);

        foreach (var observer in observers)
        {
            MessageBus.Instance.Unsubscribe(observer.Subscription, observer.Respond);
        }

        _observerList.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription).ToList().ForEach(o => _observerList.Remove(o));
    }

    public void Subscribe(string subscription, Action<object> response)
    {
        MessageBus.Instance.Subscribe(subscription, response);
        _observerList.Add(new Observer() { Subscription = subscription, Respond = response });
    }

    public void SubscribeFirstPublication(string subscription, Action<object> response)
    {
        MessageBus.Instance.SubscribeFirstPublication(subscription, response);
    }
}
```