# MVVM WPF change window and close the previous

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation, mvvm-light

As a starter in this all architecture of MVVM I'm having a few doubts regarding the navigation between one window to another. I'm using the Framework MVVM Light.

The behavior I expect is in WinForms like this:

> GeneralWindow gw = new GeneralWindow(); this.Hide(); // or close
>   gw.Show();

I already lose a couple of hours trying to find some hints using the messenger, but the methods I found I have to use code-behind in the view and that is not very MVVMish.

Best regards and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*The behavior I expect is in WinForms like this:*

```
GeneralWindow gw = new GeneralWindow(); this.Hide(); // or close gw.Show();
```

MVVM pattern divides `View` from `ViewModel`. So it is not eligible to create new `View` from `ViewModel`. **Creating window instance and showing window from view model is violation of MVVM"**. So I suggest you to use the popular technique where you can change `Views` using `ContentControl` and `DataTemplate`.

Let's dive in this technique:

```
<Window>
   <Window.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelA}">
         <localControls:ViewAUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelB}">
         <localControls:ViewBUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
   <Window.Resources>
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
</Window>
```

If `Window.DataContext` is an instance of `ViewModelA`, then `ViewA` will be displayed and `Window.DataContext` is an instance of `ViewModelB`, then `ViewB` will be displayed.

Let me show an example where it can be seen where you should put `DataTemplates`:

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleMVVMExample.ApplicationView"
        ...The code omitted for the brevity...
        Title="Simple MVVM Example with Navigation" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelA}">
         <localControls:ViewAUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelB}">
         <localControls:ViewBUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Left" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfViewModels}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                                Margin="2,5"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Border>

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentDataTemplateViewModel}" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The best example I've ever seen and read it is made by Rachel Lim. [See the example.](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

**Update:**

If you want really open new Window, then you should create an intermediate layer to make ViewModel not dependent on a concrete implementation of creating new window.

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    private readonly IWindowFactory windowFactory;
    private ICommand openNewWindow;

    public YourViewModel(IWindowFactory _windowFactory)
    {
        windowFactory = windowFactory;

        /**
         * Would need to assign value to m_openNewWindow here, and 
         * associate the DoOpenWindow method
         * to the execution of the command.
         * */
        openNewWindow = null;  
    }

    public void DoOpenNewWindow()
    {
        windowFactory.CreateNewWindow();
    }

    public ICommand OpenNewWindow { get { return openNewWindow; } }
}

public interface IWindowFactory
{
    void CreateNewWindow();
}

public class ProductionWindowFactory: IWindowFactory
{

    #region Implementation of INewWindowFactory

    public void CreateNewWindow()
    {
       NewWindow window = new NewWindow
           {
               DataContext = new NewWindowViewModel()
           };
       window.Show();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

*How to close a Window?*

[There are a lot of approaches.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945821/implementing-close-window-command-with-mvvm). One of them is:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Close()
```

Comment: Isn't a View but a Window.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Using the factory I'm having problems closing the previous window, how can I do that?